# Handling specific errors in JavaScript (think exceptions)

Tags: javascript, error-handling

How would you implement different types of errors, so you'd be able to catch specific ones and let others bubble up..?

One way to achieve this is to modify the prototype of the `Error` object:

```
Error.prototype.sender = "";


function throwSpecificError()
{
    var e = new Error();

    e.sender = "specific";

    throw e;
}
```

Catch specific error:

```
try
{
    throwSpecificError();
}

catch (e)
{
    if (e.sender !== "specific") throw e;

    // handle specific error
}
```

Have you guys got any alternatives?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

To create custom exceptions, you can inherit from the `Error` object:

```
function SpecificError () {

}

SpecificError.prototype = new Error();

// ...
try {
  throw new SpecificError;
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof SpecificError) {
   // specific error
  } else {
    throw e; // let others bubble up
  }
}
```

A minimalistic approach, without inheriting from `Error`, could be throwing a simple object having a name and a message properties:

```
function throwSpecificError() {
  throw {
    name: 'SpecificError',
    message: 'SpecificError occurred!'
  };
}


// ...
try {
  throwSpecificError();
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name == 'SpecificError') {
   // specific error
  } else {
    throw e; // let others bubble up
  }
}
```

Comment: Inheriting from `Error` has problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript/1382129#1382129

Comment: the problem with this code:
`} catch (e) {
    if (e.name == 'SpecificError') {
        // specific error
    } else {
        throw e; // let others bubble up
    }
}`
is that it will not work in IE7, raising the "Exception thrown and not caught" error. Following is the exceedingly stupid (as always) explanation from msdn:
"You included a throw statement, but it was not enclosed within a try block, or there was no associated catch block to trap the error. Exceptions are thrown from within the try block using the throw statement, and caught outside the try block with a catch statement."

Comment: Well Microsoft's C# certainly handles errors better than Javascript :P. Mozzilla added something like it to Firefox that's like that. Though it's not in the Ecmascript standard, not even ES6, but they also explain how to make it conform, though it's not as succint. Basically same as above, but using `instanceOf`. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses)

Comment: In Javascript you can throw whatever you want, be it a simple string, a number (think error code) or a fully qualified object. Sweet!

Comment: Since ES6, you can use `class SpecificError extends Error {}`.

Comment: Please note that `e.name === 'SpecificError'` is very likely to break if you are minifying your production build. Tools like UglifyJS will rename your _SpecificError_ to something shorter, hence the equality check will break. Using `e.constructor == SpecificError` should be safer to use.

Comment: @LuisNell, If you look at my code example carefully, you will see that I wasn't suggesting using the `name` property of the constructor function. I was suggesting throwing a custom made object with a `name` property, that will not break...

Comment: Please don't actually throw anything that doesn't inherit from Error. Stack trace information is attached to the Error instance. Object literals don't have this information, which will make debugging much harder if one of these things goes uncaught. Some browsers will by nice and do a weak attempt at auto-determining the stack trace if it goes uncaught, but their system is not bullet-proof.

Answer (score 22):

As noted in the comments below this is Mozilla specific, but you can use 'conditional catch' blocks. e.g.:

```
try {
  ...
  throwSpecificError();
  ...
}
catch (e if e.sender === "specific") {
  specificHandler(e);
}
catch (e if e.sender === "unspecific") {
  unspecificHandler(e);
}
catch (e) {
  // don't know what to do
  throw e;
}
```

This gives something more akin to typed exception handling used in Java, at least syntactically.

Comment: Combine with CMS's answer and it's perfect.

Comment: Conditional catch is something I either didn't know earlier or forgot about. Thanks for educating/reminding me! +1

Comment: Only supported by Firefox (since 2.0). It does not even parse in other browsers; you only get syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, this is a Mozilla-only extension, it's not even proposed for standardisation. Being a syntax-level feature there's no way to sniff for it and optionally use it either.

Comment: As an addition, regarding the proposed solution being non-standard. Quote form the [Mozilla's JavaScript Reference[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses): `This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.`

Answer (score 17):

There is unfortunately no "official" way to achieve this basic functionality in Javascript. I'll share the three most common solutions I've seen in different packages, and how to implement them in modern Javascript (es6+), along with some of their pros and cons.

### 1. Subclass the Error class

Subclassing an instance of "Error" has become much easier in es6. Just do the following:

```js
class FileNotFoundException extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    // Not required, but makes uncaught error messages nicer.
    this.name = 'FileNotFoundException';
  }
}
```

Complete example:

```js
class FileNotFoundException extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    // Not required, but makes uncaught error messages nicer.
    this.name = 'FileNotFoundException';
  }
}

// Example usage

function readFile(path) {
  throw new FileNotFoundException(`The file ${path} was not found`);
}

try {
  readFile('./example.txt');
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
    // Handle the custom exception
    console.log(`Could not find the file. Reason: ${err.message}`);
  } else {
    // Rethrow it - we don't know how to handle it
    // The stacktrace won't be changed, because
    // that information is attached to the error
    // object when it's first constructed.
    throw err;
  }
}
```

If you don't like setting `this.name` to a hard-coded string, you can instead set it to `this.constructor.name`, which will give the name of your class. This has the advantage that any subclasses of your custom exception wouldn't need to also update `this.name`, as `this.constructor.name` will be the name of the subclass.

Subclassed exceptions have the advantage that they can provide better editor support (such as autocomplete) compared to some of the alternative solutions. You can easily add custom behavior to a specific exception type, such as additional functions, alternative constructor parameters, etc. It also tends to be easier to support typescript when providing custom behavior or data.

There's a lot of discussion about how to properly subclass `Error` out there. For example, the above solution might not work if you're using a transpiler. Some recommend using the platform-specific captureStackTrace() if it's available (I didn't notice any difference in the error when I used it though - maybe it's not as relevant anymore ‍♂️). To read up more, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types) MDN page and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript) Stackoverflow answer.

Many browser APIs go this route and throw custom exceptions (as can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException))

Note that this solution may not work if you are transpiling down to to es5. In Babel version 6, [`instanceof` simply wouldn't work with subclassed builtins](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4485). In version 7, [they still warn that subclassing built-ins](https://babeljs.io/docs/caveats/#classes) may lead to unexpected issues. It's just not possible to 100% accurately transpile code like this, so all transpilers have to choose between different trade-offs.

### 2. Adding a distinguishing property to the Error

The idea is really simple. Create your error, add an extra property such as "code" to your error, then throw it.

```js
const error = new Error(`The file ${path} was not found`);
error.code = 'NotFound';
throw error;
```

Complete example:

```js
function readFile(path) {
  const error = new Error(`The file ${path} was not found`);
  error.code = 'NotFound';
  throw error;
}

try {
  readFile('./example.txt');
} catch (err) {
  if (err.code === 'NotFound') {
    console.log(`Could not find the file. Reason: ${err.message}`);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

You can, of course, make a helper function to remove some of the boilerplate and ensure consistency.

This solution has the advantage that you don't need to export a list of all possible exceptions your package may throw. You can imagine how awkward that can get if, for example, your package had been using a NotFound exception to indicate that a particular function was unable to find the intended resource. You want to add an addUserToGroup() function that ideally would throw a UserNotFound or GroupNotFound exception depending on which resource wasn't found. With subclassed exceptions, you'll be left with a sticky decision to make (Should you add two new error classes, just for this function? Or maybe add an optional property on the NotFoundError class providing more info about what wasn't found?). With codes on an error object, you can just do it.

This is the route node's fs module takes to exceptions. If you're trying to read a non-existent file, it'll throw an instance of `Error` with some additional properties, such as `code`, which it'll set to `"ENOENT"` for that specific exception.

### 3. Return your exception.

Who says you have to throw them? In some scenarios, it might make the most sense to just return what went wrong.

```js
function readFile(path) {
  if (itFailed()) {
    return { exCode: 'NotFound' };
  } else {
    return { data: 'Contents of file' };
  }
}
```

When dealing with a lot of exceptions, a solution such as this could make the most sense. It's simple to do, and can help self-document which functions give which exceptions, which makes for much more robust code. The downside is that it can add a lot of bloat to your code.

complete example:

```js
function readFile(path) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return { exCode: 'NotFound' };
  } else {
    return { data: 'Contents of file' };
  }
}

function main() {
  const { data, exCode } = readFile('./example.txt');

  if (exCode === 'NotFound') {
    console.log('Could not find the file.');
    return;
  } else if (exCode) {
    // We don't know how to handle this exCode, so throw an error
    throw new Error(`Unhandled exception when reading file: ${exCode}`);
  }

  console.log(`Contents of file: ${data}`);
}
main();
```

### A non-solution

Some of these solutions feel like a lot of work. It's tempting to just throw an object literal, e.g. `throw { code: 'NotFound' }`. *Don't do this!* Stack trace information gets attached to error objects. If one of these object literals ever slips through and becomes an uncaught exception, you won't have a stacktrace to know where or how it happened. Debugging in general will be much more difficult. Some browsers may show a stacktrace in the console if one of these objects go uncaught, but this is just an optional convinience they provide, not all platforms provide this convinience, and it's not always accurate, e.g. if this object got caught and rethrown the browser will likely give the wrong stacktrace.

### Upcoming solutions

The JavaScript committee is working on a couple of proposals that will make exception handling much nicer to work with. The details of how these proposals will work are still in flux, and are actively being discussed, so I won't dive into too much detail until things settle down, but here's a rough taste of things to come:

The biggest change to come will be the [Pattern Matching proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching), which is intended to be a better "switch", among other things. With it, you'd easily be able to match against different styles of errors with simple syntax.

Here's a taste of what this might look like:

```js
try {
  ...
} catch (err) {
  match (err) {
    // Checks if `err` is an instance of UserNotFound
    when (${UserNotFound}): console.error('The user was not found!');

    // Checks if it has a correct code property set to "ENOENT"
    when ({ code: 'ENOENT' }): console.error('...');

    // Handles everything else
    else: throw err;
  }
}
```

Pattern matching with the return-your-exception route grants you the ability to do exception handling in a style very similar to how it's often done in functional languages. The only thing missing would be the "either" type, but a TypeScript union type fulfills a very similar role.

```js
const result = match (divide(x, y)) {
  // (Please refer to the proposal for a more in-depth
  // explanation of this syntax)
  when ({ type: 'RESULT', value }): value + 1
  when ({ type: 'DivideByZero' }): -1
}
```

There's also [some very early discussion](https://github.com/wmsbill/proposal-catch-guards) about bringing this pattern-matching syntax right into the try-catch syntax, to allow you to do something akin to this:

```js
try {
  doSomething();
} CatchPatten (UserNotFoundError & err) {
  console.error('The user was not found! ' + err);
} CatchPatten ({ type: 'ENOENT' }) {
  console.error('File not found!');
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```

### Update

For those who needed a way to self-document which functions threw which exceptions, along with ways to ensure this self-documentation stayed honest, I previously recommended in this answer [a small package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/explicit-exceptions) I threw together to help you keep track of which exceptions a given function might throw. While this package does the job, now days I would simply recommend using TypeScript with the "return your exception" route for maximum exception safety. With the help of a TypeScript union type, you can easily document which exceptions a particular function will return, and TypeScript can help you keep this documentation honest, giving you type-errors when things go wrong.

Comment: Can you point to a longer discussion of the "return your exception" approach?  I think one big question I have about that approach is that I think it would result in excessive "prop drilling", in this case you'd have to handle that exception in every function in the calls stack and pass it back up to wherever it can be handled sanely.  The normal "handle exceptions at service boundaries" advice would be hard to follow.  So yeah I'm wondering how that approach really works in its entirety.

Comment: @eagspoo Try reading through [this article](https://www.hugonteifeh.com/blog/the-case-for-returning-errors) for a deeper understanding. I also threw together [a partly-contrived, but more lengthy example](https://gist.github.com/theScottyJam/084c631adc5da823e4672f0d97287cc1) showing how the return-exception pattern works. But, yes, you're absolutely right that there's a lot more boilerplate involved with returning exceptions. For this reason, I'm often switching between which approach I use, depending on the section of the codebase I'm in, and what the code is like there.

Comment: As for handling exceptions at service boundaries - that should still be followed the same no matter which approach you use - i.e. when an exception is given to you at a service boundary, you should handle it or translate it into your boundary if you feel it's necessary. Any exceptions that aren't handled/translated, are done so because they're considered "impossible to happen", or not worth the effort to handle. This all stays the same, no matter which exception-propagation technique you use (whether you propagate explicitly, through return, or implicitly, through throw).

Comment: You're saying that "If you run this in TypeScript's playground with its default settings today, it will log false:" `class MyError extends Error {}; console.log(MyError instanceof Error);` - however the same also happens in Javascript, and it's because `MyError` is indeed not an instance of `Error`. If you change it to the correct `console.log(new MyError() instanceof Error);` then it logs `true` in javascript and typescript as well.

Comment: Whoops, thanks @MikaelFinstad - I fixed that mistake.

Answer (score 12):

## [`try-catch-finally.js`](https://try-catch-finally.js.org)

Using **try-catch-finally.js**, you can call the `_try` function with an anonymous callback, which it will call, and you can chain `.catch` calls to catch specific errors, and a `.finally` call to execute either way.

### Example

```
_try(function () {
    throw 'My error';
})
.catch(Error, function (e) {
    console.log('Caught Error: ' + e);
})
.catch(String, function (e) {
    console.log('Caught String: ' + e);
})
.catch(function (e) {
    console.log('Caught other: ' + e);
})
.finally(function () {
    console.log('Error was caught explicitly');
});
```

### Example with modern arrow functions and template literals

```
_try(() => {
  throw 'My error';
}).catch(Error, e => {
  console.log(`Caught Error: ${e}`);
}).catch(String, e => {
  console.log(`Caught String: ${e}`);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(`Caught other: ${e}`);
}).finally(() => {
  console.log('Error was caught explicitly');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Module for export usage

```
/**
 * Custom InputError
 */
class InputError extends Error {
  /**
   * Create InputError
   * @param {String} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

/**
 * Custom AuthError
 */
class AuthError extends Error {
  /**
   * Create AuthError
   * @param {String} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

/**
 * Custom NotFoundError
 */
class NotFoundError extends Error {
  /**
   * Create NotFoundError
   * @param {String} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  InputError: InputError,
  AuthError: AuthError,
  NotFoundError: NotFoundError
};
```

Import into script:

```
const {InputError, AuthError, NotFoundError} = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'lib', 'errors'));
```

Use:

```
function doTheCheck = () =>
  checkInputData().then(() => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }).catch(err => {
    return Promise.reject(new InputError(err));
  });
};
```

Calling code external:

```
doTheCheck.then(() => {
  res.send('Ok');
}).catch(err => {
  if (err instanceof NotFoundError) {
    res.status(404).send('Not found');
  } else if (err instanceof AuthError) {
    res.status(301).send('Not allowed');
  } else if (err instanceof InputError) {
    res.status(400).send('Input invalid');
  } else {
    console.error(err.toString());
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

An older question, but in modern JS (as of late 2021) we can do this with a switch on the error's prototype constructor in the catch block, simply matching it directly to any and all error classes we're interested in rather than doing `instanceof` checks, taking advantage of the fact that while `instanceof` will match entire hierarchies, identity checks don't:

```js
import { SomeError } from "library-that-uses-errors":
import MyErrors from "./my-errors.js";

try {
  const thing = someThrowingFunction();
} catch (err) {
  switch (err.__proto__.constuctor) {
    // We can match against errors from libraries that throw custom errors:
    case (SomeError): ...

    // or our own code with Error subclasses:
    case (MyErrors.SOME_CLASS_THAT_EXTENDS_ERROR): ..

    // and of course, we can check for standard built-in JS errors:
    case (TypeError): ...

    // and finally, if we don't know what this is, we can just
    // throw it back and hope something else deals with it.
    default: throw err;
  }
}
```

(Of course, we could do this with an if/elseif/else too if switches are too "I hate having to use `break` everywhere", which is true for a lot of folks)

Comment: Note that [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Any particular reason you don't just do `err.constructor` instead? That would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't love any of these solutions so I made my own.  The try-catch-finally.js is pretty cool except that if you forget one little underscore (_) before the try then the code will still run just fine, but nothing will get caught ever! Yuck.

### CatchFilter

I added a CatchFilter in my code:

```
"use strict";

/**
 * This catches a specific error. If the error doesn't match the errorType class passed in, it is rethrown for a
 * different catch handler to handle.
 * @param errorType The class that should be caught
 * @param funcToCall The function to call if an error is thrown of this type
 * @return {Function} A function that can be given directly to the `.catch()` part of a promise.
 */
module.exports.catchOnly = function(errorType, funcToCall) {
  return (error) => {
    if(error instanceof errorType) {
      return funcToCall(error);
    } else {
      // Oops, it's not for us.
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

### Now I can filter

Now I can filter like in C# or Java:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject => {
   <snip><snip>
}).catch(CatchFilter.catchOnly(MyError, err =>
   console.log("This is for my error");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log("This is for all of the other errors.");
});
```

Comment: "if you forget one little underscore (_) before the try then the code will still run just fine, but nothing will get caught ever" - I'm confused how you see that behaviour since, without the `_`, `try` is considered a keyword and causes an error 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gamla`'s `throwerCatcher`:

```
export const [thrower, catcher] = throwerCatcher();

// Some function that  throws our specific exception.
const f = () => {
  thrower();
};

const fWithCatch = catcher(() => null, f); // catch with fallback

fWithCatch() // returns `null`
```

https://github.com/uriva/gamlajs