# Using and catching RangeError in javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm about to throw an exception using RangeError and wanted to check that I'm using it correctly and how to best catch it.

I have a function that could throw a RangeError OR a TypeError like this

```
function saveNumber(val) {
  // Only accept numbers.
  if (typeof val !== 'number') {
    throw new TypeError();
  }

  // Error if the number is outside of the range.
  if (val > max || val < min) {
    throw new RangeError();
  }

  db.save(val);
}
```

I'd like to call it and only deal with the RangeError. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Just don't throw a TypeError?

Comment: another piece of code may want to call this function and deal with the TypeError

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
try {
  saveNumber(...);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // ignore TypeError
  } 
  else if(e instanceof RangeError) {
    // handle RangeError
  }
  else {
    // something else
  } 
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433608/1022697)

Comment: In general you need to re-throw if you don't handle.

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [MDN documentation on try - catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
try {
    saveNumber(...);
} catch (e is instanceof RangeError) {
    // Do something
} catch (e) {
    // re-throw whatever you don't want to handle
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: JS Hint is complaining 'catch filter' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option)'. So it's a nice answer but not fully compatible.

Comment: From the same docs: "Reminder: this functionality is not part of the ECMAScript specification."

Answer (score 2):

slightly more elegant answer:

```
switch (error.constructor) {
    case NotAllowedError:
        return res.send(400);
    case NotFoundError:
        return res.send(404);
    default:
        return res.send(500);
}
```