# Catch specific Exception in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exception

I know that using following block, it is able to catch an `Exception`.

```
try{
    // Code
}catch(err){
    alert(err.message);
}
```

Say, I want to catch a `NumberFormatException`. How can I catch a specific `Exception` using `JavaScript`?
(I actually want to catch `NumberFormatException`, `InterruptedException`, `ConnectException` which are well defined in `Java`)

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. There is no `NumberFormatException` in JavaScript, nor `InterruptedException`, nor `ConnectException`. JavaScript has as much in common with Java as a manhole has with a man. If you wish to know whether a string is a well-formed number or not, use `isNaN()` on the result of `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Example:_Handling_a_specific_error

Comment: this thread has more answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433558/handling-specific-errors-in-javascript-think-exceptions

Answer (score 8):

Javascript has no standard way of doing this.

```
try{
    // Code
}catch(err){
    if(err instanceof SomeException){
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

Firefox has an [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), which I think is nice and should be more standard.