# Handling exceptions in node js like java?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, exception

I want to build a node application and I  want to handle the exception,
in java we use exception class to handle exceptions,how can I do the same with node.
Do I have any library for handling exception in node?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), this is really powerful object which represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation. This brings you really easy way to handle the errors.

In case you want to extend some Exception class, there is no point of doing it because JS is not strictly typed language as Java. Thus when you do *catch* you will be catching all the errors that can appear in a *try* block and you cannot specify which exception class you want to use unless you will be verifying the *instance* of the error which looks not good at all.

```
try {
    throw new SpecificError;
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SpecificError) {
        // specific error
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Have a look also into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433558/handling-specific-errors-in-javascript-think-exceptions).

And as [GreenLAge4964](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6733110/greenlake4964) said, it is good to search.

Comment: yes I am agree,but cant we use any library, like how we extend exception class in java application?

Comment: I have edited my answer.