# Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

In JavaScript we have a few ways of getting the properties of an object, depending on what we want to get.

1) `Object.keys()`, which returns all own, enumerable properties of an object, an ECMA5 method.

2) a `for...in` loop, which returns all the enumerable properties of an object, regardless of whether they are own properties, or inherited from the prototype chain.

3) `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` which returns all own properties of an object, enumerable or not.

We also have such methods as `hasOwnProperty(prop)` lets us check if a property is inherited or actually belongs to that object, and `propertyIsEnumerable(prop)` which, as the name suggests, lets us check if a property is enumerable.

With all these options, there is no way to get a **non-enumerable, non-own** property of an object, which is what I want to do. Is there any way to do this? In other words, can I somehow get a list of the inherited non-enumerable properties?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question answered the question I was going to ask: How to inspect non-enumerable properties (just to explore what is available in predefined objects). Finally I found getOwnPropertyNames! :-)

Comment: @marcus :-) That's what SO is all about!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Since `getOwnPropertyNames` can get you non-enumerable properties, you can use that and combine it with walking up the prototype chain.

```js
function getAllProperties(obj){
    var allProps = []
      , curr = obj
    do{
        var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(curr)
        props.forEach(function(prop){
            if (allProps.indexOf(prop) === -1)
                allProps.push(prop)
        })
    }while(curr = Object.getPrototypeOf(curr))
    return allProps
}

console.log(getAllProperties([1,2,3]));
```

I tested that on Safari 5.1 and got

```bash
> getAllProperties([1,2,3])
["0", "1", "2", "length", "constructor", "push", "slice", "indexOf", "sort", "splice", "concat", "pop", "unshift", "shift", "join", "toString", "forEach", "reduceRight", "toLocaleString", "some", "map", "lastIndexOf", "reduce", "filter", "reverse", "every", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "valueOf", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__lookupSetter__"]
```

---

**Update:** Refactored the code a bit (added spaces, and curly braces, and improved the function name):

```
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  var props = [];

  do {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
      if (props.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
        props.push(prop);
      }
    });

    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  } while (obj);

  return props;
}
```

Comment: Thanks toby, one thing I don't understand is the line:
`while(curr = Object.getPrototypeOf(cure))`, as the conditional statement uses an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator, wouldn't this always return true? Or is this line essentially checking whether "curr" has a prototype?

Comment: @AlexNabokov it will return false if the result is falsy, which will occur when `Object.getPrototypeOf(cure)` returns `null` at the top of the prototype chain. I guess this assumes no circular prototype chains!

Comment: @Domenic All prototype chains end with the `null` value. The do-while loop iterates over every object in the prototype chain and ends when `null` is reached. Btw prototype chains can never be circular (since you cannot modify the implicit prototype link of an object *after* it has been created).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas you seem to be correct; I thought you could do something weird with constructor functions but after hacking away in the console for 10 minutes can't seem to make anything circular happen.

Comment: @Alex `Function.prototype` can never be the "root" prototype, since it's prototype link points to `Object.prototype`. The function `Object.getPrototypeOf( obj )` returns the topmost object in the prototype chain of `obj`. It enables you to follow the prototype chain of `obj` until you reach its end (the `null` value). I'm not sure what your issue with this is...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas For example, if I create a constructor: `function Boy() { this.height = "tall" }` and then an instance of it: `John = new Boy()`, and do `Object.getPrototypeOf(John)`, I will get `undefined`. But if I do `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor` recursively, it will correctly return the chain John -> Boy -> Object. Only then can I capture the properties of each "chainling" in the chain.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas PS I'm new to this so could be way off :) but isn't the topmost object in the prototype chain always `Object()`? I thought `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` will return the obj's constructor's prototype, which is immediately before it in the chain.

Comment: @Alex No, it's not `undefined`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(John)` returns the `Boy.prototype` object (as it should) - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/aeGLA/1/. Note that the constructor `Boy` is **not** in the prototype chain of `John`. The prototype chain of `John` is as follows: `Boy.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`.

Comment: "*I thought Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) will return the obj's constructor's prototype*" - Yes. In the case of `John`, his constructor is `Boy`, and the `prototype` property of `Boy` is `Boy.prototype`. So `Object.getPrototypeOf(John)` returns `Boy.prototype`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Aaah OK my understanding of what a prototype chain is was a bit off then :) Thanks for bearing with my noob-ness.

Comment: Doesn't this answer need to de-dupe the property names to have clean behavior (say if you want to iterate through all the properties of an object)?

Comment: Instead of `props = props.concat(x)` use `props.apply(props, x)`

Comment: This will error out if the argument provided is null or undefined.

Comment: Props (pun intended, for fun ;-) ) to this answer as it has inspired some of Mozilla's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#obtaining_properties_by_enumerabilityownership

Answer (score 20):

A cleaner solution using recursion:

```
function getAllPropertyNames (obj) {
    const proto     = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    const inherited = (proto) ? getAllPropertyNames(proto) : [];
    return [...new Set(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).concat(inherited))];
}
```

### Edit

More generic functions:

```
function walkProtoChain (obj, callback) {
    const proto     = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    const inherited = (proto) ? walkProtoChain(proto, callback) : [];
    return [...new Set(callback(obj).concat(inherited))];
}

function getOwnNonEnumPropertyNames (obj) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
        .filter(p => !obj.propertyIsEnumerable(p));
}

function getAllPropertyNames (obj) {
    return walkProtoChain(obj, Object.getOwnPropertyNames);
}

function getAllEnumPropertyNames (obj) {
    return walkProtoChain(obj, Object.keys);
}

function getAllNonEnumPropertyNames (obj) {
    return walkProtoChain(obj, getOwnNonEnumPropertyNames);
}
```

This same template can be applied using `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`, etc.

Answer (score 15):

### Update Jan 2022 -- almost every answer combined, plus symbols (ES6+)

After seeing [Mozilla's JS documentation specifically say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps): "no single mechanism iterates all of an object's properties; the various mechanisms each include different subsets of properties."... I had exactly this question albeit newer because I want symbol keys also and I think all the answers above pre-date those).

I came here hoping someone else knew how to create such a single mechanism.

No single answer on this page seems to cover EVERYTHING, but between all of them, I think it can be done -- including the option to also exclude the annoying [top level keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460640/4516124).

In exploring [the code in Mozilla's JS doc'n](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#obtaining_properties_by_enumerabilityownership) that [airportyh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024294/271577) inspired, plus [the table below it on that same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#detection_table) I discovered the new `Reflect.ownKeys`.  That catches everything (including symbols)... except inherited properties, but airportyh's answer walking the prototype chain fixes that.

So... combining all those findings and simplifying as much as I could, I came up with the following two functions, that (I believe) DO catch EVERYTHING.  Posting in case it helps anyone else.

### Option 1. Simple: Return EVERY Key, no exceptions

Returns every key, enumerable or not, string, symbol, own, inherited, and top level.

```
function getAllKeys(obj) {
    let keys = [];
    // if primitive (primitives still have keys) skip the first iteration
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
    }
    while (obj) {
        keys = keys.concat(Reflect.ownKeys(obj));
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

I really like the simplicity, though I wonder if I've missed anything.  If any one catches any errors in that, please do let me know.

### Option 2. Flexible: Return EVERY Key, with optional exclusions

Adds:

1. a filter function based on a bunch of one line functions (easier to debug that way, and this ain't code golf )  that determine if any given key should be excluded, based on the parameters passed in,
2. a condition to walk the prototype chain or not (per [airportyh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024294/271577)), and,
3. a condition to stop or not before the top level is reached (per [Maciej Krawczyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460640/4516124)).

Include or exclude:

- enumerable keys
- non-enumerable keys
- symbol keys
- string keys
- own keys
- inherited keys
- top level keys.

*(On a side note, I'm no JS expert, so maybe I'm missing something. I'm a little confused why no one else here has used Array.prototype.filter(), since isn't that exactly what we're doing?)*

I believe the following covers it. By default everything is included except top level keys. Adjust to taste. Again I'd welcome feedback if any errors here:

```
function getAllKeysConditionally(obj, includeSelf = true, includePrototypeChain = true, includeTop = false, includeEnumerables = true, includeNonenumerables = true, includeStrings = true, includeSymbols = true) {
    
    // Boolean (mini-)functions to determine any given key's eligibility:
    const isEnumerable = (obj, key) => Object.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj, key);
    const isString = (key) => typeof key === 'string';
    const isSymbol = (key) => typeof key === 'symbol';
    const includeBasedOnEnumerability = (obj, key) => (includeEnumerables && isEnumerable(obj, key)) || (includeNonenumerables && !isEnumerable(obj, key));
    const includeBasedOnKeyType = (key) => (includeStrings && isString(key)) || (includeSymbols && isSymbol(key));
    const include = (obj, key) => includeBasedOnEnumerability(obj, key) && includeBasedOnKeyType(key);
    const notYetRetrieved = (keys, key) => !keys.includes(key);
    
    // filter function putting all the above together:
    const filterFn = key => notYetRetrieved(keys, key) && include(obj, key);
    
    // conditional chooses one of two functions to determine whether to exclude the top level or not:
    const stopFn = includeTop ? (obj => obj === null) : (obj => Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === null);
    
    // and now the loop to collect and filter everything:
    let keys = [];
    while (!stopFn(obj, includeTop)) {
        if (includeSelf) {
            const ownKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj).filter(filterFn);
            keys = keys.concat(ownKeys);
        }
        if (!includePrototypeChain) { break; }
        else {
            includeSelf = true;
            obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

*As noted by Jeff Hykin in the comments these solutions use*  `Reflect` *and arrow functions which are new in ES6.  Therefore ES6 minimum required.*

Comment: Criminally underrated answer (1 other upvote as of writing). Should probably add an Ecmascript version warning though (e.g. when does it stop working: ES5/ES6/ES7)

Comment: @JeffHykin, Thanks! (for the feedback, and the edit).  Admittedly, I'm not certain what you mean by your "when does it stop working" point. I think you mean "what's the earliest version of ES that it works in (whereas it fails in any version previous to that)"...? I think the newest functionality it uses is the Reflect.ownKeys(), but I can't seem to find anything on when that was introduced.  I'd welcome any assistance with this.

Comment: Welcome! And yes, my comment should say "when does it start working". Reflect is from ES6, and I'm confident thats the only version-dependent feature for `getAllKeys`. For the `getAllKeysConditionally`, arrow functions are also ES6 and default values are ES5. So overall this should work for ES6 and newer 

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the info!   Added ES6+ to the heading, and a note at the end.

Comment: A--Option 1 will include duplicate keys. That's why the other ES6 answers use Sets. B--For the record, my answer does mention that it can be used to get Symbols, etc., albeit as a footnote. For example, `walkProtoChain(obj, Reflect.ownKeys)` will retrieve all keys. C--"no one else here has used Array.prototype.filter()" I did ;) That said, most answers don't use it because it's not necessary. The question was about string properties, of which almost any subset can be directly queried without any filtering.

Comment: A-- Good point (duplicate keys), with sets as the solution, although what if I want ALL keys, somehow, even the duplicates (ie. I want some record of the duplicates, though I'm not sure what would be the appropriate representation of that)?  I can think of a couple of ideas to solve that, but now getting even more beyond the scope of the original question.    B. Yes, fair enough.  C. Fair enough again. Apologies, I missed your use of filter. 

Answer (score 5):

Straight forward iterative in ES6:

```
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
    let result = new Set();
    while (obj) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => result.add(p));
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return [...result];
}
```

Example run:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  let result = new Set();
  while (obj) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(p => result.add(p));
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  return [...result];
}

let obj = {
  abc: 123,
  xyz: 1.234,
  foobar: "hello"
};

console.log(getAllPropertyNames(obj));
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of Sets leads to a somewhat cleaner solution, IMO.

```
const own = Object.getOwnPropertyNames;
const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf;

function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
    const props = new Set();
    do own(obj).forEach(p => props.add(p)); while (obj = proto(obj));
    return Array.from(props);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to log non enumerable properties of a parent object ex. by default the methods defined inside a class in es6 are set on prototype but are set as non-enumerable.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all inherited properties or methods for some instance you could use something like this

```
var BaseType = function () {
    this.baseAttribute = "base attribute";
    this.baseMethod = function() {
        return "base method";
    };
};

var SomeType = function() {
    BaseType();
    this.someAttribute = "some attribute";
    this.someMethod = function (){
        return "some method";
    };
};

SomeType.prototype = new BaseType();
SomeType.prototype.constructor = SomeType;

var instance = new SomeType();

Object.prototype.getInherited = function(){
    var props = []
    for (var name in this) {  
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty(name) && !(name == 'constructor' || name == 'getInherited')) {  
            props.push(name);
        }  
    }
    return props;
};

alert(instance.getInherited().join(","));
```

Comment: Better to use `Object.getInherited` rather than `Object.prototype.getInherited`. Doing that also removes the need for the ugly `!(name == 'getInherited')` check. Also, in your implementation, the `props` array can contain duplicate properties. Lastly, what's the purpose of ignoring the `constructor` property?

Comment: When will object.getInherited will become true? Please check below question as I am stuck with inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718345/javascript-unable-to-access-same-object-method-after-object-createbaseobject/31719231?noredirect=1#comment51377720_31719231

Comment: IMHO - these belong to Reflect, not to Object. Or - alternatively - I'd expect from the language Object.keys(src, [settings]) where optional settings can specify if to include non-ninumerables, if to include inheritted, if to include non-enumerable inheritted, if to include own, if to include symbols, and perhaps to what max inheritance depth to dig.

Comment: uh... same for Object.entries. Not sure about Object.values though. ...well. why not.

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't want to include Object prototype properties such as `__defineGetter__`, `hasOwnProperty`, `__proto__` and so on.

This implementation allows you to either include or exclude Object prototype properties:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(object, includeObjectPrototype = false) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);

  let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
  const objectProto = Object.getPrototypeOf({});

  while (proto && (includeObjectPrototype || proto !== objectProto)) {
    for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
      if (props.indexOf(prop) === -1) {
        props.push(prop);
      }
    }
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
  }

  return props;
}
```

```
console.log(getAllPropertyNames(new Error('Test'), true));
// ["fileName", "lineNumber", "columnNumber", "message", "toString", "name", "stack", "constructor", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "__defineGetter__", "__defineSetter__", "__lookupGetter__", "__lookupSetter__", "__proto__"]
```

```
console.log(getAllPropertyNames(new Error('Test'), false));
// [ "fileName", "lineNumber", "columnNumber", "message", "toString", "name", "stack", "constructor" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I came up with while studying the subject. To get all non-enumerable non-own properties of the `obj` object do `getProperties(obj, "nonown", "nonenum");`

```js
function getProperties(obj, type, enumerability) {
/**
 * Return array of object properties
 * @param {String} type - Property type. Can be "own", "nonown" or "both"
 * @param {String} enumerability - Property enumerability. Can be "enum", 
 * "nonenum" or "both"
 * @returns {String|Array} Array of properties
 */
    var props = Object.create(null);  // Dictionary

    var firstIteration = true;

    do {
        var allProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
        var enumProps = Object.keys(obj);
        var nonenumProps = allProps.filter(x => !(new Set(enumProps)).has(x));

        enumProps.forEach(function(prop) {
            if (!(prop in props)) {
                props[prop] = { own: firstIteration, enum_: true };
            }           
        });

        nonenumProps.forEach(function(prop) {
            if (!(prop in props)) {
                props[prop] = { own: firstIteration, enum_: false };
            }           
        });

        firstIteration = false;
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));

    for (prop in props) {
        if (type == "own" && props[prop]["own"] == false) {
            delete props[prop];
            continue;
        }
        if (type == "nonown" && props[prop]["own"] == true) {
            delete props[prop];
            continue;
        }

        if (enumerability == "enum" && props[prop]["enum_"] == false) {
            delete props[prop];
            continue;
        }
        if (enumerability == "nonenum" && props[prop]["enum_"] == true) {
            delete props[prop];
        }
    }

    return Object.keys(props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNonEnumerableNonOwnPropertyNames( obj ) {
    var oCurObjPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    var arReturn = [];
    var arCurObjPropertyNames = [];
    var arCurNonEnumerable = [];
    while (oCurObjPrototype) {
        arCurObjPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(oCurObjPrototype);
        arCurNonEnumerable = arCurObjPropertyNames.filter(function(item, i, arr){
            return !oCurObjPrototype.propertyIsEnumerable(item);
        })
        Array.prototype.push.apply(arReturn,arCurNonEnumerable);
        oCurObjPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(oCurObjPrototype);
    }
    return arReturn;
}
```

Example of using:

```
function MakeA(){

}

var a = new MakeA();

var arNonEnumerable = getNonEnumerableNonOwnPropertyNames(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation in my personal preferences :)

```
function getAllProperties(In, Out = {}) {
    const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(In);
    keys.forEach(key => Object.defineProperty(In, key, {
        enumerable: true
    }));
    Out = { ...In, ...Out };

    const Prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(In);
    return Prototype === Object.prototype ? Out : getAllProperties(Proto, Out);
}
```