# How can I list all the properties of Math object?

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
for (var i in window) console.log(window[i])
```

I get a list of window properties and methods

Howver when I do the same for "Math" object, I get nothing.

```
typeof "window" == typeof "Math"
```

returns **TRUE**, so I do not see a reason why my loop is not working.

It's strange as if I write directly `Math['E']` I get the value of constant **E**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not all object properties are iterable. You'll only get iterable properties in a `for..in` loop.

Since most properties of `window` (which happens to be the global object) are user-defined global variables, they are enumerable.

In modern JavaScript engines you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` to get all properties, both enumerable and non-enumberable:

```
>>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)
["toSource", "abs", "acos", "asin", "atan", "atan2", "ceil", "cos", "exp", "floor", "log", "max", "min", "pow", "random", "round", "sin", "sqrt", "tan", "E", "LOG2E", "LOG10E", "LN2", "LN10", "PI", "SQRT2", "SQRT1_2"]
```

See [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation! But is there a way to enumare properties of Math object in this case ?

Answer (score 8):

```
["max", "ceil", "SQRT2", "PI", "pow", "log", 
"LOG2E", "tan", "sqrt", "exp", "random", "min",
"floor", "atan2", "cos", "atan", "acos", "abs", 
"round", "asin", "LN2", "LOG10E", "sin",
"E", "SQRT1_2", "LN10"].forEach( function(key ) {
    if( Math[key] ) {
        console.log( key, Math[key] );
    }
});
```

You can get a list of those keys in a modern browser with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Math );` The above works in all noteworthy browsers provided you [shimmed .forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
let a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);
a.forEach((element) => console.log(element));
```