# Is it possible to iterate over the static variables and methods of a class with CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Using CoffeeScript, I would like to be able to iterate over the static methods and variables of a class. More specifically, I'd like to gain access to all of the functions in `Math`.

I'm looking for functionality similar to:

```
for x in Math
    console.log (x + ": " + Math[x])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a previous `stackoverflow` question: [How can I list all the properties of Math object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756948/how-can-i-list-all-the-properties-of-math-object)

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Math )
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes but what you need to do is iterate over the Object's prototype. In CoffeeScript it would look like this:

```
for key, value of MyClass.prototype
  console.log key, ':', value
```

EDIT:

In JavaScript it would be this:

```
var i;
for (i in MyClass.prototype) {
  // This condition makes sure you only test real members of the object.
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(MyClass.prototype, i)) {
    console.log(i, ':', MyClass.prototype[i]);
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

One caveat: this will not work with *native JavaScript constructors* so `Math` is a bad example. If you are using custom class constructors, it will work fine.

Comment: You didn't check it, did you?

Comment: Sorry guys. You're right. It doesn't work because Math is a native constructor. This only works on custom constructors. See my edit.

Comment: So, is this just not at all possible then?

Comment: Sorry @jeremynealbrown I don't think so. And I think the reason why is that those functions are not normal functions and wouldn't work if you tried to apply them in other contexts. For example, this line: `console.log(Array.prototype.map)` yields this result: `function map() { [native code] }`. That [native code] part means the function is not implemented in JavaScript so it's special and apparently they don't want you to be able to do other things with it.