# How to Bring All of an Objects Properties ForeFront?

Tags: javascript, math

## Begin:

The `Math` object in JavaScript can prove to be extremely useful. In a page using the `Math` object repeatedly, I would rather not continuously use. I would prefer to use these functions at top-level. I will provide an example on how this is possible:

#### The With Keyword (Bad Way):

Let me state the following: This is absolutely terrible, never use it.

```js
with(Math) {
    let q = min(10,211);
    let r = max(2,8);
    let e = random();
    let p = floor(e*r)
    console.log(q*r/e)
}
```

#### Bringing an Object to Front By Defining It As Such (Good Way):

I enjoy using this way much more than the way above.

```js
let {min,max,random,floor} = Math;
let q = min(10,211);
let r = max(2,8);
let e = random();
let p = floor(e*r);
console.log(q*r/e);
```

## Continuation:

I am asking if anyone knows of a way to accomplish what the `with` keyword does without `with` because I find `with` terrible. I am curious to know if it is possible to get all of the words of `Math` and store it into an `Object` that is defined as `Math`. I understand that this may be confusing. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You've already got a good solution

Comment: Not really, not without `eval` or something similarly gross. Explicitly declare all variables up-front and things will be fine and more maintainable.

Comment: let {min,max,random,floor, ...other} = Math, don't know what actually you want

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the goal is to "globalize" **all** `Math` objects, so they can be accessed from `window`.

Comment: I'm more confused `Math` is already in the global scope. Use `Math.<method>`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox He's trying to use them without having to write `Math.` all the time.

Comment: The properties of `Math` are not enumerable, so I don't think there's a way to get them all automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordinary objects (instances of the `Object` class) you could use `Object.assign` to add their properties to the `window` object. But for `Math` and the other [base objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) their properties seem not to be enumerable. Instead, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756948/how-can-i-list-all-the-properties-of-math-object) you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to find all the properties of Math and attach them to the window object.

```
for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)) {
    window[prop] = Math[prop];
}

console.log(PI); // 3.14...
```

I would suggest this is not a great practice as it is not very transparent about what names are being added to the global namespace.

Comment: Good find. You could also check whether there's already a conflicting global name, and not overwrite it.