# Is there anyway to pass an object from SilverLight to JavaScript without serializing?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

Suppose I have a class in SilverLight:

```
public class GenericClass {

    public string filedOne = "field one";

    public string filedTwo = "field two";

}
```

And I want to pass an instance of it to JavaScript to access in the following way:

```
function callback(obj) {
    console.log(obj.fieldOne);
}
```

Is this possible without serializing to JSON and back?

**UPDATE:**

I know how to pass primitive values - that's not a problem. I need to pass an object with several fields.

Comment: By definition, if you're passing it from SL to JS you *are* serializing it.....

Comment: I mean I do not want to do any serialize/unserialize operations myself, if silverlight-to-js bridge does it behind the curtains it's ok. So... any idea how I can achieve this, or if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class TestPage: UserControl
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.SomeMember = "TEST";
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("JSFunction", myObject);
    }        
}
```

UPDATE:
In order to pass non-primitive type objects to javascript; the class definition shall be marked with `ScriptableType` attribute. All properties of this class shall also be marked with `ScriptableMember` attribute.

```
[ScriptableType]
public class MyClass
{
    [ScriptableMember]
    public string SomeMember { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: I can pass primitive variable, that's not a problem. I need to pass an object, just as I described.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ScriptableTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptabletypeattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
[ScriptableType]                       
public class SMT_ScriptableManagedType
    {
    [ScriptableMember(EnableCreateableTypes = false)] // No access
     public string GetString1()
        { return "abcdefg"; }

     public string GetString2()            // Can be accessed.
        { return "123456"; }
}
```

Now you can [pass the object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645074%28v=vs.95%29) like this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ReceiveSMT", new SMT_ScriptableManagedType());
```

Where ReceiveSMT is a javascript function which will receive the object as a parameter.

Comment: And how do I access the members of that object? It is a bit different pattern anyway. Is it impossible to keep it the way I described above?

Comment: just use them. there is nothing special about those.

Comment: I need it differently. Actually I found that I can mark class field as [ScriptableMember] too and then instance is in fact passed to JavaScript callback. The problem is that the resulting object is not enumerable, therefore I can't do anything to it, unless I'm aware of it's structure. And I'm not. Do you know howto make it enumerable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object to get the non-enumerable properties.

Comment: Awesome! Although not supported in IE8 and less (http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), which makes it useless for me :|