# can members of javascript objects be iterated in full?

Tags: javascript, object, reflection

I would like to be able to iterate through **all** the members of an object.  something like this:

```
 function reflect(obj) {
 var str = "";
 for (member in obj) { str += (member + "\n"); }
 return str;
 }
```

but the *Enumerable* flag prevents many of the members to apear in the *for in* loop.
   my question is:

1. is there another way to iterate through an object's members that exposes **all of them**?
2. if not, is there some access to these flags? (can **I** set *Enumerable* to true?)
3. is there a way to expose the prototype chain and determine which member belongs to which ancestor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getOwnPropertyNames`for that. It returns all properties regardless of the enumerable option.

```
var objectProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
```

**Update** This is only available for Javascript 1.8.5 and newer! (thanks @Kiyura)

Comment: Note that this is only available in Javascript 1.8.5 or later. (ES5)

Comment: It is, thanks, I'll add it to my answer for completeness sake

Comment: thats pretty good, thanks! so this returns properties that are not inherited.. it does not count for functions though, like for-in does.. but it's interesting to see that event handlers (like onclick) are not considered functions unless they actually have a function assigned to them.(if you check their type they claim to be an object..)