# Extending the native JavaScript Error constructor

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, custom-error-handling

I tried to extend the JavaScript error properties through the extension of the prototype of the Error constructor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// extending the Error properties to all the ones available in the various browsers:
Error.prototype = {
    name: null, // (all browsers); the name of the error
    message: null, // (all browsers); the error message as a string
    description: null, // (Internet Explorer); description of the error
    fileName: null, // (Firefox); the name of the file where the error occurred
    lineNumber: null, // (Firefox); the number of line where the error occurred
    columnNumber: null, // (Firefox); the number of column where the error occurred
    number: null, // (Internet Explorer); the error code as a number
    stack: null // (Firefox, Chrome); detailed information about the location where the error exactly occurred
};

function log(error) {
    var errors = [];

    for (var prop in error) {
        errors.push(prop + ': ' + error[prop]);
    }

    alert(errors.join('\n'));
}
</script>
```

Then I test the log function:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
try {
    var a = b; // b is undefined!
} catch(error) {
    log(error);
}
</script>
```

The result is that the error object only shows some properties (e.g. on Firefox `fileName`, `lineNumber` and `columnNumber`) like if it has not been extended.

But the most strange thing is that the `for...in` cycle seems **unable to walk all the error object properties**: trying to alert the standard property `error.message` normally returns a message.

So the results of my test are:

1. the Error constructor is not extensible through its prototype, as other native constructors are;
2. the `for...in` loop is not able to walk the properties of an error object.

Am I right?
Are there some interesting evidences/resources you may suggest to know more about it?

Comment: `Error` is a host object and therefore does not have to behave like "normal" JavaScript objects.

Comment: Mmh, interesting, I did not know about host objects. I am learning through something about through Stackoverflow threads. As for now, I understood they are special objects with special properties and behaviours, such as DOM objects, am I right?

Comment: See http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8. If you search for `host object` on this site you'll find some interesting statements about them. *edit*: They are basically objects supplied the environment and not part of the specification (just like DOM objects, yes). But the problem is probably just that `Error.prototype` is not writable (at least in Firefox). `var obj = {foo: 'bar'}; Error.prototype = obj; Error.prototype == obj;` results in `false`.

Comment: Even non host objects may have non enumerable properties, btw.

Comment: I see... And there's no control over the _enumerability_ of properties, right? AFAIK, I read about the `enumerable` attribute of an object property only in the new ECMA script 5.1 draft http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @Emanuele: You only have control over properties *you* create.

Comment: @dystroy: Yay, just like the `length` property in arrays, which is not enumerated in a `for...in` loop. AFAIK, there's no way to make a custom property not enumerable.

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande Yes you can : [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 1):

A. Like, Raynos said, The reason `message` isn't being set is that `Error` is a function that returns a new Error object and does *not* manipulate `this` in any way.

B. The way to do this right is to return the result of the apply from the constructor, as well as setting the prototype in the usual complicated javascripty way:

```
function MyError() {
    var tmp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
    tmp.name = this.name = 'MyError'

    this.stack = tmp.stack
    this.message = tmp.message

    return this
}
    var IntermediateInheritor = function() {}
        IntermediateInheritor.prototype = Error.prototype;
    MyError.prototype = new IntermediateInheritor()

var myError = new MyError("message");
console.log("The message is: '"+myError.message+"'") // The message is: 'message'
console.log(myError instanceof Error)                // true
console.log(myError instanceof MyError)              // true
console.log(myError.toString())                      // MyError: message
console.log(myError.stack)                           // MyError: message \n 
                                                     // <stack trace ...>
```

The only problems with this way of doing it at this point (i've iteratted it a bit) are that

- properties other than `stack` and `message` aren't included in `MyError` and
- the stacktrace has an additional line that isn't really necessary.

The first problem could be fixed by iterating through all the non-enumerable properties of error using the trick in this answer: [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object), but this isn't supported by ie<9. The second problem could be solved by tearing out that line in the stack trace, but I'm not sure how to safely do that (maybe just removing the second line of e.stack.toString() ??).