# Javascript getOwnPropertyNames

Tags: javascript

This method returns all numerable and non-enumerable properteis as follow:
**Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)**

> > length,
> >     prototype,
> >     defineProperty,
> >     getOwnPropertyDescriptor,
> >     defineProperties,
> >     create,
> >     seal,
> >     freeze,
> >     preventExtensions,
> >     isSealed,
> >     isFrozen,
> >     isExtensible,
> >     getPrototypeOf,
> >     keys,
> >     getOwnPropertyNames,
> >     caller,
> >     arguments

But the internal prototype and scope property are not displayed why?What properties are displayed with this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object

Comment: The internal prototype is not a property so it doesn't show up, and I'm not sure what you mean by scope properties. Please give more specific examples.

Comment: @loganfsmyth internal scope[[scope]]

Comment: @Maizere That's not a property, for example you can't do `obj['internal scope[[scope]]']`. Chrome displays it in the console to be helpful but it a property of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal prototype is not a property so it doesn't show up. Some browsers expose it as `__proto__`, but it is not enumerable and is non-standard.

Similarly, 'internal scope' is not a property, for example you can't do obj['internal scope[[scope]]']. Chrome displays it in the console to be helpful but it a property of the object.