# print the javascript string object properties and methods

Tags: javascript

How to print the properties and methods of javascript String object.

Following snippet does not print anything.

```
for (x in String) {
   document.write(x);   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The properties of `String` are all non-enumerable, which is why your loop does not show them. You can see the own properties in an ES5 environment with the [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) function:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String);
// ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "fromCharCode"]
```

You can verify that they are non-enumerable with the [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) function:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String, "fromCharCode");
// Object {value: function, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

If you want to see `String` instance methods you will need to look at `String.prototype`. Note that these properties are also non-enumerable:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype);
// ["length", "constructor", "valueOf", "toString", "charAt"...
```

Answer (score 2):

First It must be declared as Object,(may be using 'new' keyword)

```
s1 = "2 + 2";               
s2 = new String("2 + 2");   
console.log(eval(s1));      
console.log(eval(s2));
```

OR

```
console.log(eval(s2.valueOf()));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the console in developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

and try this

```
    for (x in new String()) {
       console.log(x);   
    }
```

Comment: minil wants the methods and properties of the `String` object, not the ones of *a* string object.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
 var StringProp=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String);

 document.write(StringProp); 

 -->>  ["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "fromCharCode"]
```

But you might be more interested by :

```
 var StringProtProp=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype);

 document.write(StringProtProp); 

-->> ["length", "constructor", "valueOf", "toString", "charAt", "charCodeAt", "concat", 
"indexOf", "lastIndexOf", "localeCompare", "match", "replace", "search", "slice", "split", 
"substring", "substr", "toLowerCase", "toLocaleLowerCase", "toUpperCase", "toLocaleUpperCase",
 "trim", "trimLeft", "trimRight", "link", "anchor", "fontcolor", "fontsize", "big", "blink", 
"bold", "fixed", "italics", "small", "strike", "sub", "sup"]
```

Comment: `document.write`? seriously?