# Object is empty but object property is not?

Tags: javascript, titanium

Under what circumstances would it be possible that an object is empty, but a property of that object is not?

Code:

```
console.log('type: '+typeof(widget));
console.log('obj: '+JSON.stringify(widget));
console.log('data: '+JSON.stringify(widget.data));
```

Output:

```
[INFO] :   type: object
[INFO] :   obj: {}
[INFO] :   data: {"index":2}
```

Additionally, `for (var prop in widget)` does not execute, and trying to call `widget.hasOwnProperty('data')` throws an error.

Edited to add: I should have specified that this is in Titanium, not straight JS, hence the `console` calls are the Titanium calls and not Firebug etc.

Comment: `console.log(widget)` will (at least in FF and Chrome) display the *full/live* object graph - note that this is off of the value, not the stringification of such.

Answer (score 3):

if `data` isn't an enumerable property, it's not stringified. That's probably what happens here.

See [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to have a deeper understanding of not enumerable properties and their creation.

Note that you can use the console in a more efficient way :

```
console.log(typeof(widget), widget);
console.dir(widget);
```

It's not just for strings.

*As an aside I just coded today a stringifier taking not enumerable properties into account : [JSON.prune](http://dystroy.org/JSON.prune/).*

Comment: Thank you, I checked out defineProperty and figured this was the answer. However, I then tried the function here to output all properties, even enumerable and inherited: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object

...and 'data' still is not listed. Any thoughts?

Comment: For reference, here is the output of that function:

`["__TI","constructor","toString","hasOwnProperty","valueOf","__defineSetter__","__lookupGetter__","toLocaleString","__defineGetter__","propertyIsEnumerable","__lookupSetter__","isPrototypeOf"]`

Comment: @wizzard without your object it's hard to tell. You might try to stringify it with *my* stringifier (link in answer). But there might be other traps that I can't guess without code.

Comment: I wish I had the code. `widget` is created inside a compiled Titanium module, so I have no view into that.

Comment: It might be interesting to also log `typeof widget.data`. Sometimes you encounter strange things, like that trick in V8 which makes some objects of type undefined..

Comment: Wow. I won't say it was enlightening but it was certainly unexpected: Simply adding `console.log(typeof(widget.data));` caused the following error:

`*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: title)`

Comment: Yeah, it's looking that way. Hopefully I can get a response from them. Thanks for all your help thus far.

Comment: If you get an answer, please keep us informed. It might be very interesting (and I know a few good JS coders who would probably be interested too).