# How to inspect the default object properties in the Node REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, prototype

I am using Node REPL. When we define a `constructor` function like one here:

```
function Rabbit() { }
```

It's `prototype` object i.e `Rabbit.prototype` have the `constructor` property which can be referenced like this:

```
>> Rabbit.prototype.constructor
   [Function: Rabbit]
```

This `constructor` property does not get listed in the `Rabbit.prototype` object but doing `Rabbit.prototype.constructor` and `Rabbit.prototype["constructor"]` gives this info appropriately.

```
>> Rabbit.prototype
   {}
```

**a)** How can I view these default properties like `constructor`, `hasOwnProperty`, `toString`,`valueOf` etc. ? In **browser** while using the **console**, I get a nice little dropdown for that. I am expecting some kind of `dir` command for that.

**b)** And why there `inherited` properties are not shown, when I fire `Rabbit.prototype` in the console ? Is it desired because we want to show only **user** added stuff ?

**c)** And where are they actually defined `Object` or `Function` ?

**EDIT :-** Seems like these are added up to `Object.prototype` . Reference :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Also,

```
>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)
[ 'constructor',
  'toString',
  'toLocaleString',
  'valueOf',
  'hasOwnProperty',
  'isPrototypeOf',
  'propertyIsEnumerable',
  '__defineGetter__',
  '__lookupGetter__',
  '__defineSetter__',
  '__lookupSetter__' ]
```

Do we need to recursively traverse the prototype chain by applying `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` on each object for listing the **owned** and **inherited** ones ?

Regards.

Comment: Where exactly are you inspecting that?

Comment: Guess what, there's also a ton more it's not showing you, like `toString`, `hasOwnProperty` and other built in methods. Your question should really be: how to get the Node REPL to show default object properties?

Comment: @deceze, Yeah I am working on that. Was taking a screenshot for that. Changing the tittle.

Comment: @Giannis No. Nope. Nope, nope, nope. No. Nein.

Comment: @deceze, `Rabbit.prototype` inherits there from `Object.prototype` or what ?

Comment: have you tried `for (var name in Rabbit.prototype) {console.log(name)}`  ?

Comment: @maioman , not working ! `undefined`

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Rabbit.prototype)`

Comment: @jcubic, worked actually but what about the other ones `toString` etc. I need to view all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is required to move down the `prototype chain` by applying `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to get list of non-enumerable properties also. Got it from here :

### [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object)