# JavaScript unable to access same object method after object.create(baseObject)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to javascript. I have written some code by incorporating suggested answers. Now the code block is working in once scenario and not working in other scenario.

```
<script langugage="JavaScript">

var baseObject = {
    name:"sunrise",
    age:39,
    printProperties:function(){
        console.log("Base class-> Name:Age:"+this.name+":"+this.age);
    }
}
baseObject.printProperties();
console.log(baseObject); 

/* This code block works fine */

var derivedObject2=Object.create(baseObject);
    derivedObject2.education="M.C.A"
    derivedObject2.printProperties=function(){  
        console.log("Derived -> Name:Age:Education:"+this.name+":"+this.age+":"+this.education);
    }
 derivedObject2.printProperties();
 console.log(derivedObject2);


/*
derivedObject.__proto__ = baseObject;
derivedObject.printProperties(); // Works fine
*/

/* This code block does not work  */

var derivedObject=Object.create(baseObject,{
      education:{value:"MCA"},
      //education:"MCA",
      printProperties:function(){  
        console.log("Derived -> Name:Age:Education:"+this.name+":"+this.age+":"+this.education);
        return this;
      }
});

derivedObject.printProperties(); // Getting error here, 
console.log(derivedObject);


</script>
```

Here is my error:

```
Error:  Uncaught TypeError: derivedObject.printProperties is not a function
```

Comment: `prototype` is a special property of **functions**. If you want to change the prototype of an *existing* object, you have to use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Comment: If you want to mimic inheritance, you'll have to learn about `call`, `apply` and `bind`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Use `__proto__` if available: `derivedObject.__proto__ = baseObject;` or just borrow the method (see [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) .

Comment: __proto__solved the problem for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.create()`

```
var baseObject = {
    name:"sunrise",
    age:39,
    printProperties:function(){
        console.log("Name:Age:"+this.name+":"+this.age);
    }
}
```

then

```
var derivedObject=Object.create(baseObject);
    derivedObject.education="M.C.A"
    derivedObject.printProperties=function(){  
 console.log("Name:Age:Education:"+this.name+":"+this.age+":"+this.education);
        }
 derivedObject.printProperties();
```

now the derivedObject will inherit all the properties of the base object

**edit**
you can do this

```
var derivedObject=Object.create(baseObject,{
              education:{value:"MCA"},
              printprop:function(){}
});
```

`Object.create()` abstracts most of the complexity that is associated with the prototypes

Comment: I want complete declaration of derivedObject on the lines of baseObject i.e, attributes & methods together so that code readability & maintenance is good. By keeping declarations of both objects intact, can you achieve the result using create function?

Comment: derivedObject.printProperties(); throwing below exception : uncaught type error: derivedObject.printProperties is not a function

Comment: @sunrise76 you can only define getters and setters in `object.create()` and using a extra line of declaration will not  increase ur code complexity instead it will be more readable to others

Answer (score 0):

prototype is the property for constructor functions in javascript. But you are trying to implement prototype in object. That is not possible.

Please see the example for implement prototype concept.

```
function baseObject (){
    this.name = "john";
    this.age = 25;
}
function derivedObject (){
    this.gender = "male";
    this.occupation = "Engineer";
}

derivedObject.prototype = new baseObject();
var d = new derivedObject();
console.log(d.name);
console.log(d.gender);
```

Comment: *"That is not possible."* That's incorrect. JavaScript provides `Objet.setPrototypeOf` and `__proto__` in object literals (though not every browser might support it yet).

Comment: I am able to implement object prototyping with  __proto__   as suggested by  CPH4