# reference a DOM element as a property of the window object

Tags: javascript

According to [this blog post](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/07/19/dom-element-references-as-global-variables/) it is possible to reference DOM elements as named properties of the `window` object (based on their `name` attribute). The above code shows that indeed the form can be accessed as `window.aform`. Yet why does it fail to find the property when iterating over all properties of `window`?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name='aform'>
    </form>
    <script>
     // get all properties, including non-enumerable ones: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024294/274677
     function getAllProperties(obj){
       var allProps = [], curr = obj;
       do {
         var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(curr)
           props.forEach(function(prop){
             if (allProps.indexOf(prop) === -1)
               allProps.push(prop)
           })
       } while(curr = Object.getPrototypeOf(curr))
         return allProps
     }
     var findIn = function(x,y) {
       var ps = getAllProperties(x);
       for (var i = 0 ; i < ps.length; i++) {
         var propertyName = ps[i];
         try {
           if (x[propertyName]===y)
             return 'found as property ['+propertyName+']';
         } catch (e) {
           console.log('failed to read property ['+propertyName+'] due to: ['+e.name+']');
         }
       }
       return "not found";
     }
     console.log(findIn(window, window.aform));
     console.log(window['aform']===window.aform);
     console.log(window.aform);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the above page loads, I see on the console:

```
not found
true
<form name="aform"></form>
```

Comment: I get the error `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` when trying it in Firefox, in the `findIn` function when trying to read all properties in the window object.

Comment: @Guffa I get a similar error when trying in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AAlQkzO5BYdwRR1f8NdL. I have been able to see the console output without exceptions when opening the file from Chrome from the local file system.

Comment: @Guffa updated the code (also in Plunker in the link given above) so that it doesn't fall off the loop when the `SecurityError` happens.

Comment: @Guffa latest Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/L78kPTqvwGSGgC20HcUV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers add the form reference as a property to the `window` object, some only make it available so that you can read it like a property but it's not actually added as a property.

When I try it in Firefox it finds the property, but in Chrome, IE and Edge it's not found.

The safest way to get the form by name is by using the `document.forms` collection, where it's clearly defined that the forms are available.

Comment: "only make it available so that you can read it like a property but it's not actually added as a property." How is this done?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: Probably by letting the property reader read from other collections also, similar to how the `window.all` collection in earlier IE read from several other collections. For a precise answer to that you would need to dig into the actual implementation of each browser.