# Javascript - list all properties

Tags: javascript, list, properties, prototype, chain

How to list all properties(methods and attributes) in an object and it's prototype chain?
I'm interested in all of them (enumerable, and not enumerable).

Target browser - chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for(var k in obj) {
    console.log(k, obj[k]) // name, value
}
```

Example:

```js
var obj1 = { a: 10, b: "x", c: { no: "no" }}
var obj2 = new Object(obj1)
obj2.d = "yes"

for (var k in obj2) {
  console.log(k, obj2[k]) // name, value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in all of them (enumerable, and not enumerable).

You can't enumerate *what's not enumerable*. Actually you can define not enumerable properties to avoid them appear as part of an iterator like a `for...in` or `Object.keys`. See this other Q&A to learn more about a workaround: [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object)

For now, the easiest way of iterating all properties, both *own properties* and *prototype's properties* is using a `for...in` loop:

```
for(var propertyName in obj) {

}
```

And you can use `Object.hasOwnProperty` to check if a property isn't declared on the given object prototype:

```
for(var propertyName in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
       // It's not from the object's prototype...
   }
}
```