# Does javascript have something like Object.assign that includes enumerable: false properties when copying objects?

Tags: javascript

It seems that `Object.assign` does not assign properties that are not enumerable.

```
var weasel = {test: 1};
Object.defineProperty(weasel,
          'isFetching',
          {
            value: true,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false
          })
Object {test: 1, isFetching: true}
Object.assign({}, weasel);
Object {test: 1}
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Andreas You probably want `Object.create(Object.prototype, …)` though - or even with `Object.getPrototypeOf(weasel)`. Or use `Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(weasel))` instead

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object/8024294#8024294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```
x=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(weasel).reduce((a,b)=>(Object.defineProperty(a,b,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(weasel,b)),a),{})
```

Comment: @Andreas `Object.assign` doesn't either? OP only asked to work around non-enumerability, not to copy descriptors

Comment: I screwed this around to work... I suppose I will make it look pretty. This doesn't clone the prototype but then all you'd need to do to achieve that is use object.create