# Iterate over anonymous object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have the following object containing arrays :
[image: Example data]

I am iterating over it to get its key value like to use it further, Using `for in` to get the data inside of it.

```
for (let key in gameObj){
    console.log(key);
}
```

But its not even getting into the loop in order to get the arrays.
What am i missing ?

Comment: What is `gameObj`? Are you sure that it's your actual object? You don't have JSON data or anything?

Comment: Looks like it should work fine to me. Are you sure `gameObj` is defined when the loop starts?

Comment: code looks fine to me. share your code where you are writing this code.

Comment: Please post the `gameObj` variable, and not just a picture of it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes thats the actual object. I have updated the question image please have a look.

Comment: @ObsidianAge i have checked the type of it. like console.log(typeof gameObj) and it says `object`.

Answer (score 2):

I would add this a comment but don't have the reputation yet.
See [Is it possible to get the non-enumerable inherited property names of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object/8024294])

```
function getAllProperties(obj){
    var allProps = []
      , curr = obj
    do{
        var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(curr)
        props.forEach(function(prop){
            if (allProps.indexOf(prop) === -1)
                allProps.push(prop)
        })
    }while(curr = Object.getPrototypeOf(curr))
    return allProps
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine. Check the fiddle.

```js
        
    var gameObj = {
    "key1" : ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    "key2": ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",]
    }
    
    for(var i in gameObj){
    alert(i);
    }
```

Comment: Not working, I have updated the question image, Please have a look there.

Comment: I get the output. I meant can you share the code? I believe you are missing something basic. it happens to me all the time. LOL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the object in a `for` loop `key` will be the key, then you just call it like you would an array:

```js
const gameObj = {
   '99lEEbmV7s': ['37966', '37966', '37965', '37966', '0'],
   'TggZdsbcje': ['37966', '37966', '37965', '37966', '0']
};

for (let key in gameObj){
    console.log(gameObj[key]);
}
```

Comment: Not working, I have updated the question image, Please have a look there.