# Why does looping over the properties of an object and using tab autocomplete in Node Js result in a different list of properties for an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, javascript-objects, node-modules

For example, I'm trying to find all of the methods and properties associated with the events.EventEmitter class.  Using a for loop such as

```
for(i in events.EventEmitter) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

results in a much smaller and incomplete list of properties for the class... However, if I just type into the REPL 'events.EventEmitter.' and hit tab twice, it brings up the much larger, complete list.

Why is this?  And where do all of these extra hidden properties come from?

Comment: `in` iterates only Enumerable properties.

Comment: @Keith How can I get all of the properties, even if they aren't enumerable or owned by the object?

Comment: You could try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024149/is-it-possible-to-get-the-non-enumerable-inherited-property-names-of-an-object