# Throwing custom exceptions in Javascript. Which style to use?

Tags: javascript, exception, custom-exceptions

Douglas Crockford recommends doing something like this:

```
throw {
    name: "System Error",
    message: "Something horrible happened."
};
```

But you could also do something like this:

```
function IllegalArgumentException(message) {
    this.message = message;
}

throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument cannot be less than zero");
```

and then do:

```
try {
    //some code that generates exceptions
} catch(e) {    
    if(e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
        //handle this
    } else if(e instanceof SomeOtherTypeOfException) {
        //handle this
    }
}
```

I guess you could include a `type` property in Crockford's implementation and then examine that instead of doing an `instanceof`. Is there any advantage from doing one versus the other?

Comment: For someone used to Java-style exceptions, the second form looks much... more familiar.

Comment: Yes, I'm partial to the second for that very reason. :)

Comment: I am in favor of the second one since it is more reusable in terms of code purity. To be precise, if I am about to throw the same exception type on several places, my code would get messy (immense) with the first approach.

Comment: @bellpeace Good point. I like the encapsulation advantage that it offers. Indeed, I am throwing exceptions in several places and the first approach is starting to get unwieldy. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Update 2022

If your environment supports ES6, you should use inheritance from `Error` class, as [recommended by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types):

```
class IllegalArgumentException extends Error {
   // ...
}
```

This is also the most upvoted answer in [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript).

---

### Pre-ES6 (original answer)

Also pre-ES6 environments provide the [Error class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) as basis for exceptions. It already allows you to define a message, but also provides a useful stack property to track down the context of the exception.
You can create your own exception type by using prototypical inheritance. There are already several stackoverflow discussions (for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript)), how to do this properly. However, I had to dig a little bit until I found the correct and modern approach. Please be aware that the approach that is suggested in the Mozilla documentation (see above) is not liked by the stackoverflow community. After a lot of reading I came out with that approach for inherit from Error.prototype:

```
function IllegalArgumentException(sMessage) {
    this.name = "IllegalArgumentException";
    this.message = sMessage;
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
IllegalArgumentException.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
IllegalArgumentException.prototype.constructor = IllegalArgumentException;
```

Comment: This version still works correctly in Node v16 and the `.throw` / `.throws` assertion in chaijs.

Answer (score 4):

I am in favor of the second one since it is more reusable in terms of code purity. To be precise, if I am about to throw the same exception (even the same exception type with a different message) on several places, my code would get messy (immense) with the first approach.