# Chai: how can I check exception properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

Consider a piece of code below:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

parse = function() {
  throw {error: 'PROTOCOL_ERROR'}
}

describe('parser', function() {

  it('throw error on unfinished command', function() {
    try {
      parse("*2\r\n$4\r\necho\r\n$11\r\nhel")
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e).to.equal({error: 'PROTOCOL_ERROR'})
    }
  })
});
```

Is there a way to avoid this `try...catch` boilerplate in the code? Chai has 'throw' method but it provides only an `instanceof` check

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

parse = function() {
  throw {error: 'PROTOCOL_ERROR'}
}

describe('parser', function() {
  it('throw error on unfinished command', function() {
      expect(
        () => parse("*2\r\n$4\r\necho\r\n$11\r\nhel")
      ).to.throw().which.has.property('error', 'PROTOCOL_ERROR');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be throwing an instance of `Error` or something that extends `Error`

```
parse = function() {
  throw new Error('PROTOCOL_ERROR');
}
```

Then `chai` has a method to assert that a function is throwing an error
http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw

So the final thing should look like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

parse = function() {
  throw new Error('PROTOCOL_ERROR');
}

describe('parser', function() {

  it('throw error on unfinished command', function() {

    expect(function() { parse("*2\r\n$4\r\necho\r\n$11\r\nhel") }).to.throw(Error, 'PROTOCOL_ERROR');

  })
});
```

Edit: wrapped function call in function. Otherwise the error is thrown before expect is called and has a chance to catch it.

Comment: You can only assert that the error was thrown using a specific constructor and what the message is. What property are you trying to check?

Comment: No matter what the property.
look for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24078053/1907902 
it can be sMessage, for example.

Comment: Then you can't avoid the boilerplate above using chai. Just a warning, if you write it with a `try{}catch{}` and it doesn't throw nothing will be asserted and it will pass

Comment: yep, you understand the problem now:)

Comment: Thanks for you answer

Comment: Hey, I think your sample is incorrect. The test doesn't pass

Comment: Can you include the expected and actual values it provides?

Comment: @kharandziuk I edited my answer slightly. You pass the function without invoking it to expect. Otherwise it is called right away without giving it a chance to catch it