# How to throw InvalidArgumentException JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, throw

### Objective

Throw InvalidArgumentException in a JavaScript method like one does in Java or similar languages.

### Background

I have been trying to familiarize myself with JavaSctipt error handling, and I know I can throw exceptions using the `throw` keyword.

To achieve this, I read the [throw documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) and the [Error documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) as well.

### Problem

So far this is my code:

```
if (mySize >= myArray.length)
    throw new Error("InvalidArgumentExcpetion - BANG!!!!");
```

This code has some problems for me:

1. I have the text in the exception itself. Right now I have BANG, but tomorrow I may want BONG and if I decide to change it, I have to look everywhere!
2. I am using an Error, and not really a new object with the type InvalidArgumentExcpetion. Is this the correct way?

### Questions

So now I am confused.

1. Should I create a new object like in the throw documentation, or create an Error Message?
2. Doesn't JavaScript have a InvalidArgumentException object that I can use?
3. How should I proceed in order to have a maintainable way to throw errors **that uses ECMA6**?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077681/throwing-custom-exceptions-in-javascript-which-style-to-use

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After doing research, I now have come down to a solution that I like. Special kudos to Toan, I would gladly chose his answer, but since I do feel that it is still a little bit incomplete, I decided to create my own answer with my own findings. Hope it helps someone !

### Problems:

1. Using the solution proposed by Toan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146237/1337392
2. It is a possible, albeit if you want customization you do need to create your own object.

### Answers:

1. If you want to handle exceptions based on their types like in Java, you should create a new object like in the document. (by *Toan Nguyen*)
2. Javascript does not have ***InvalidArgumentException*** (by *Toan Nguyen*)
3. After reasearching, this solution is the one I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32750746/1337392

### Credits:

- Toan Nguyen, for the first answers and his great ideas
- David Wickström, for suggesting an article that led to an article that led to a blog where the answer I was looking for was.

Thanks for all the help guys! kudos++ for all!

Answer (score 9):

> I have been trying to familiarize myself with JavaSctipt [*sic*] error handling, and I know I can throw exceptions [....] but tomorrow I may want BONG [....]

You could throw a [`TypeError`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/typeerror) or a [`SyntaxError`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/syntaxerror) if they make more sense. But no need to get too fancy. Simply throw an [`Error`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/error) with a message as it looks as though you're already doing:

```
if (myArray && myArray.length < mySize) throw new Error('`mySize` must be larger');
```

And if you decide tomorrow you want BONG:

```
if (!myBong) throw new Error('Officer, that is not `myBong`');
```

For more info on built-in errors types, [read the docs](https://devdocs.io/javascript/errors).

Answer (score 8):

Please see the answer below:

1. If you want to handle exceptions based on their types like in Java, you should create a new object like in the document.
2. If you don't want to look for the message everywhere, create a new error list like you do in Java. For instance:

   ```js
   let errors = {
       invalidOperation: 'Invalid operation',
       unAuthorized: 'You are not authorized to use this function',       
   }
   ```

   and use them instead of hard-coded strings like

   ```js
   throw new InvalidOperationException(errors.invalidOperation);
   ```
3. JavaScript does not have ***InvalidArgumentException***.

Comment: So, you are saying I have to create my own object, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do if you have logic handling exceptions based on their types. If you just have a simple try/catch {}, and then work on the message then you can use the generic Error type.

Comment: is `InvalidOperationException` something that JavaScript has, or did you create it? I could not find any references to it in the `Error` doucmentation.

Comment: I created InvalidOperationException. Javascript does not have such an error.