# How to throw error properly for a missing property?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

```
    if (win.NS && win.NS.molist && win.NS.molist.utility) {
        NS = win.NS;
        NS.molist.dom = true;
    } else {
        throw "dom requires utility module";
    }
```

For the snippet above, what is the proper way to throw an error, if `win.NS.molist.utility` does not exist?

Can I just throw up the text I want displayed to be shown in the debugger?

Perhaps, I should use one of the built in error types?

Maybe a `new TypeError`, I'm not sure as there are many global Errors objects.

Comment: throw new Error("dom requires utility module"); I don't understand your problem ([error types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_types))

Comment: [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `throw` a completely custom *Error*.

```
function ModuleNotFoundError(message) {
  this.name = "ModuleNotFound";
  this.message = message || "dom does not have this module";
}
ModuleNotFoundError.prototype = new Error();
ModuleNotFoundError.prototype.constructor = ModuleNotFoundError;

throw new ModuleNotFoundError('win.NS.molist.utility');
```