# What is prototype.constructor for?

Tags: javascript

In continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845385), what is prototype.constructor for?

I thought that by simply doing:

```
new some_object()
```

that the function object became a constructor.  I don't understand why you would need to set it in this manner.

```
some_object.prototype.constructor = some_object;
```

Comment: you don't need to set it... new does that for you.

Comment: The `constuctor` property is used when you get handed an object and want to know what function constructed it.

Comment: @dandavis You need to (re)set it when overwriting a prototype completely. `Foo.prototype = { ... }` clobbers `Foo.prototype.constructor` with `Object`.

Comment: I think this can help you: http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/

Comment: @apsillers : you just mentionned a common misunderstanding : constructor is refering to the constructor function, which does not change when you change the function's prototype. Setting again the constructor is useless.  (see http://jsbin.com/iraseg/1/edit and  watch the console results if in doubts).

Comment: (see jsbin.com/iraseg/1/edit and watch the console results if in doubts)

Comment: @VincentPiel We're not talking about `Type.constructor` (which your code tests, and remains `Function` as long as the constructor is a function), but rather we're talking about `Type.prototype.constructor`, which is used as `instance.constructor`. Setting `Type.prototype` certainly does change `Type.prototype.constructor` (and therefore changes `instance.constructor`), but obviously leaves `Type.constructor` unchanged.

Comment: @VincentPiel Here is a test that correctly examines `Whatever.prototype.constructor` and shows that the two are not the same: http://jsbin.com/iraseg/2/edit. In particular, the reason it's a problem is that the `constructor` property for *instances* of `Whatever` get their value from `Whatever.prototype.constructor`. The problem has nothing to do with `Whatever.constructor`, which is gets its value from `Function.prototype.constructor`, as `Whatever` an instance of `Function`.

Comment: Look at your comments. This is not what you said. No one serious will get an instance of a Class, then after override this Class prototype to get some other instances. This is a non-issue. I won't argue no more since it's just too obvious.

Comment: @VincentPiel Are you simply objecting to my assertion that a *real-world* function would ever *use* an instance's `constructor` property, e.g., as `makeNewObjectWithSameType` does [in my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17886590/710446)? In that case, I'm certainly don't disagree; I merely wanted to show how it *might* be used, not that such a pattern ever *should* be used. (I assume by "this is not what you said" you're referring to my first comment, since my second comment seems to be nearly verbatim in alignment with my later comments.)

Comment: @VincentPiel In any case, I'm sorry I've misunderstood your point -- I get the sense from your comment we both agree here, but I've simply misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Comment: I guess using too few words is the root of many evils down there. :-) Best regards.

Comment: perhaps I didn't follow the conversation correctly, but jQuery does in fact create an instance of an object and than immediately set the prototype to something else...this is a real use case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose class `A` inherit `B` using the following:

```
A.prototype = new B();
```

After this `A.prototype.constructor == B`. So instances of `A` have a constructor from `B`. It's a good practice to reset a constructor after the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a function that takes an object and constructs a *new instance* of that object's type:

```
function makeNewObjectWithSameType(typedObject) {
    return new typedObject.constructor();
}
```

There is *why* you might need a `constructor` property.

But `constructor` is already set when you define your constructor -- why would you need to define it again? Consider the following case:

```
function Foo() {
    // constructor logic...
}
Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo; // true by default

var f = new Foo();
f.constructor == Foo; // true!
```

But now consider that `Foo.prototype` is overwritten:

```
function Foo() {
    // constructor logic...
}
Foo.prototype = {
    // new prototype; this is an `Object`
}
Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo; // FALSE! Foo.prototype is an Object
// thus, constructor == Object

var f = new Foo();
f.constructor == Foo; // FALSE! again, this is Object
```

If you passed in `f` to my `makeNewObjectWithSameType` function above, it would construct an `Object`, rather than a `Foo`.

You can solve this by manually resetting `Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;` after you reassign `Foo.prototype` to a new object.