# What is prototype.constructor and its role in the prototype chain - Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I was reading about prototypal inheritance in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), I found this code snippet.

```
function B(a, b){ }
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {});
B.prototype.constructor = B;
var b = new B();
```

For simplicity, I have removed the inner content of the functions. Here `B.prototype.constructor` is assigned to B, once it is created. Why this is done and what is role of prototype.constructor in the prototype chain. I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886395/what-is-prototype-constructor-for) question and one answer is

> It's a good practice to reset a constructor after the assignment.

I would like to get a good explanation on this and what is the effect on this in the prototype chain. In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) Object.prototype.constructor is explained as

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.

I have tried out following

```
function A(name) {
  this.name = name
}
function B() {
  this.getName = function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
var b = new B();
```

Here `b.constructor` is `function A(name)` and also there is another constructor available in `b.__proto__.constructor` and both are same. What is the difference between these two. Now when I did the following `B.prototype.constructor == B`, `b.constructor` is `function B()`

Now I have created a new object from `b`

```
var c = Object.create(b)
```

So how this is going to affect the prototype chain.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a function, e.g.

```js
function A() {}
```

automatically it receives a `prototype` property, which is an object with a `constructor` property, which is the function:

```js
A.prototype.constructor === A;
```

This `constructor` property is not used internally by JS, so you can change it, remove it, or do what you want.

However, some codes rely on that property to get the constructor from its prototype, or from instances that inherit from that prototype. So it's better practice not to modify it.

If you replace the prototype with a new object, you are removing that `constructor` property. So it's better to reset it:

```js
function A() {}
function B() {}
B.prototype.constructor; // B
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor; // A
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.constructor; // B
```

Comment: Constructor property only enable when you initialize with new key word.

Comment: @MdAtiqulHaque: Not sure what you mean. `.constructor` is not initialised with a `new` call, and if you don't call `A` with `new` then you don't create an instance obviously.