# Applying properties of a base type to a subtype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, type-systems, function-composition, subtype

I would like to include the properties and initialization logic from a "base" type into a "sub" type in JavaScript. Is the following idiomatic?

```
function Base(arg1) {
    this.foo = arg1.foo;
}

function Sub(arg1) {
    //Initialize using the base ctor...
    Base.call(this, arg1);
}
```

Comment: So when someone does `var x = new Sub('abc')` you want that `x.foo === 'abc'`?

Comment: Yes this is one of the possible ways. Just the disadvantage that Base function gets called when Sub instance is instantiated.

Comment: @deitch yes, I want the initialization logic in the base, run when initializing the sub type

Comment: Assuming the base and child constructor having the same signature, you could also do `Base.apply(this, arguments)` to add some flexibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (but just `this.foo = arg1` in the `Base`, not `arg1.foo`), that's the typical way you set up a base/derived relationship with JavaScript's prototypical inheritance and constructor functions. Here's the complete pattern:

```js
function Base(arg1) {
  this.foo = arg1;
}
Base.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  snippet.log("doSomething says foo is " + this.foo);
};

function Sub(arg1) {
  //Initialize using the base ctor...
  Base.call(this, arg1);
}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
Sub.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {
  snippet.log("doSomethingElse says foo is " + this.foo);
};

// Usage
var s = new Sub('bar');
snippet.log("s.foo = " + s.foo);
s.doSomething();
s.doSomethingElse();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I have a script, [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/), that makes it more declarative, encourages private resources, and makes calls to parent "class" methods easier. But that script will be obsoleted by ES6's classes, which despite being called classes are still prototypical in nature. (And there are transpilers for ES6's class syntax that generate ES5 code, so you can use the new syntax now, it just means you need a build step before using the result.)

If you need to support really old browsers (like IE8) that don't have `Object.create`, you can shim the one-argument version of it used above:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The second argument of Object.create cannot be shimmed.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor();
     };
}
```

Note that constructor functions are just one way you can use prototypical inheritance in JavaScript, not the only way. But if you're using constructor functions, that's the pattern.

Comment: Is using anther constructor for initialisation purposes, but without modifying the prototype chain still idiomatic?

Comment: @Ben: I've not seen it done, no. Since `Base` is a constructor function (denoted by the capital `B`), in theory it could rely on something on the prototype it assigns to instances that won't be there if you haven't set up the relationship. Of course, if you write both of them, you know it won't do that, but I would say that's not really idiomatic at that point. Probably better to attach a function to `Base` (say, `Base.setup = function(obj, arg1) { ... };`) and then use `Base.setup(this, arg1)` in `Sub`. That way it's clear `obj` may be anything. (`Base` would also do that, for code reuse.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so:

```
//Local
function fn()
  {
  var foo = [];
  foo.toUpperCase = String(foo).toUpperCase;
  foo.push("a");
  foo.toUpperCase();
  }
fn();

//Global
foo = [];
window.toUpperCase = function (obj) {return String(obj).toUpperCase();}
foo.push("a");
toUpperCase(foo);

//Prototype
foo = [];
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = String.prototype.toUpperCase;
foo.push("a");
foo.toUpperCase();

//Constructor Prototype
foo = [];
Array.prototype.constructor = String.prototype.toUpperCase;
foo.push("a");
foo.constructor();

//toString override
foo = [];
foo.push("a");
var bar = String(foo);
foo.toString = function() { return bar.toUpperCase(); }
foo.toString();
```

The built-in `Error` object uses the following idioms:

- Methods

  > The global Error object contains no methods of its own, however, it does inherit some methods through the prototype chain.
- Error instances

  > All Error instances and instances of non-generic errors inherit from Error.prototype. As with all constructor functions, you can use the prototype of the constructor to add properties or methods to all instances created with that constructor.
- Error types

  > Besides the generic Error constructor, there are six other core error constructors in JavaScript:

  1. EvalError

     > Creates an instance representing an error that occurs regarding the global function eval().
  2. RangeError

     > Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a numeric variable or parameter is outside of its valid range.
  3. ReferenceError

     > Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when de-referencing an invalid reference.
  4. SyntaxError

     > Creates an instance representing a syntax error that occurs while parsing code in eval().
  5. TypeError

     > Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.
  6. URIError

     > Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when encodeURI() or decodeURI() are passed invalid parameters.

**References**

- [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1382107/1113772)
- [ReferenceError - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)
- [The art of throwing JavaScript errors, Part 2 - NCZOnline](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/)
- [Creating defensive objects with ES6 proxies - NCZOnline](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/04/22/creating-defensive-objects-with-es6-proxies/)
- [Web workers: errors and debugging - NCZOnline](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/25/web-workers-errors-and-debugging/)
- [Meta programming with ECMAScript 6 proxies](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-proxies.html)