# Expressjs - Handling Errors With Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm building an API (using Expressjs v4) and typically I've dealt with errors within the route rather than using middleware. For example:

```
router.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
  if (err)
    return res.status(500).send({type: "serverError", message: "Something has gone wrong on our end."});
}
```

I now realise that middleware is the "way to go." I've seen the rather limited documentation on the Expressjs site here: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html but still unsure of a few things.

I've added in the `server.js`:

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {

}
```

**but how do I supposed to handle the different types of errors (400,404,500 etc)?**

I'm finding myself writing 3 lines of code each time an error occurs:

```
//A route
var err = new Error();
err.status = 404;
return next(err);
```

and I can access the status using:

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err.status);
  if(err.status == "400")
    //do something
  else
    //etc etc
}
```

Surely there's an easier way than this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create your own Error type that allows you to provide all the information necessary to act on the error.

```
var util = require('util');

function HttpError(message, statusCode){
    this.message = message;
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}

util.inherits(Error, HttpError);
module.exports = HttpError;
```

Then include your new error object in your code and use it like

```
next(new HttpError('Not Found', 404));
```

Or you could go crazy and implement an error type for each response code pre-populating the `statusCode` part.

Ref: [What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript)

Comment: You can omit the `this.stack` part if you don't need the stack trace, but it's super helpful sometimes

Answer (score 4):

Instead manually creating *error*, you can delegate that error like below.

```
return next(err);
```

And your error will go deep down all the routes defined until it find routes with below signature.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

});
```

You can see the *err* argument in above route.

Ideally you can use below two methods for both DEVELOPMENT & PRODUCTION environment.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        logger.log('info', err.message + " expected URL was " + req.url);
        res.status(err.status).send(err.status, {
            message: err.message,
            error  : err
        });
    });
}

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    logger.log('error', err.message + " expected URL was " + req.url);
    res.status(err.status).send(err.status, {
        message: err.message,
        error  : {}
    });

});
```

You can capture actual populated *error* object in there.

Comment: but the `err` won't have `status` though will it unless I manually set it as in my question right??? - and those three lines I'm trying to avoid because I will have to do this for every error.

Comment: Not every error comes with status. but you are using [callbacks](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) or aren't you !

Comment: Yeah I'm using callbacks

Comment: The thing is I need to create errors for things like MissingToken and TokenNotFound etc etc

Comment: If you want to set status code for every other error, you have to do it manually and delegate that error as per workflow i mentioned. We are using 500 status code for such errors.