# TypeScript error TS2345 when rejecting a Promise with an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, promise, tsc

I have a TypeScript error message whose error I do not understand. The error message is:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: Error) => void | Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => IdentityKeyPair | PromiseLike'.
>     Type 'void | Promise' is not assignable to type 'IdentityKeyPair | PromiseLike'.

My code was working fine but TypeScript got mad at me when I changed this block:

```
.catch((error) => {
  let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
  return this.store.save_identity(identity);
})
```

into this:

```
.catch((error) => {
  if (error instanceof RecordNotFoundError) {
    let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
    return this.store.save_identity(identity);
  } else {
    return reject(error);
  }
})
```

Here is the complete code which was working:

```
public init(): Promise<Array<Proteus.keys.PreKey>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.store.load_identity()
      .catch((error) => {
        let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
        return this.store.save_identity(identity);
      })
      .then((identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair) => {
        this.identity = identity;
        return this.store.load_prekey(Proteus.keys.PreKey.MAX_PREKEY_ID);
      })
      .then((lastResortPreKey: Proteus.keys.PreKey) => {
        return resolve(lastResortPreKey);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

And here is the code which **does not compile** anymore:

```
public init(): Promise<Array<Proteus.keys.PreKey>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.store.load_identity()
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error instanceof RecordNotFoundError) {
          let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
          return this.store.save_identity(identity);
        } else {
          return reject(error);
        }
      })
      .then((identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair) => {
        this.identity = identity;
        return this.store.load_prekey(Proteus.keys.PreKey.MAX_PREKEY_ID);
      })
      .then((lastResortPreKey: Proteus.keys.PreKey) => {
        return resolve(lastResortPreKey);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

Does anyone sees why the TypeScript compiler refuses my `return reject(error);` statement with error code `TS2345`?

**Screenshot:**

[image: error TS2345]

I am using TypeScript 2.1.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out below.  When you are in a then or catch block you can return a Promise or a value which gets wrapped into a Promise.  You are manually working with a Promise yourself so you can just call the resolve and reject handlers without needing to return anything.  Returning `reject(error)` would try to take that returned value, wrap it in a Promise and then try to pass to the next `then` block which is why you were getting the error you did.  Think of it this way: returning something in a handler means continue down the chain with this new value.  In your case I think you just want to stop the chaining and have the Promise you are creating resolve or reject under certain conditions.

```
public init(): Promise<Array<Proteus.keys.PreKey>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.store.load_identity()
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error instanceof RecordNotFoundError) {
          let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
          return this.store.save_identity(identity);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      })
      .then((identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair) => {
        this.identity = identity;
        return this.store.load_prekey(Proteus.keys.PreKey.MAX_PREKEY_ID);
      })
      .then((lastResortPreKey: Proteus.keys.PreKey) => {
        resolve(lastResortPreKey);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: If I just do `reject(error)` instead of `return reject(error)`, then I am receiving `error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.`.

Comment: I changed it to throw the error which will just be caught by the catch at the bottom achieving the same thing.

Comment: Since you are not doing anything in your last `.then` block I would also just resolve in the previous one as Kulvar showed you.  It's up to you if you pass reject as he did or catch the error manually and call reject yourself.  I like doing so as I find it easier to read but it's slightly more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop a Promise chain (cancellation aside), not even by `return`ning `reject()`, which is a definite misuse of Promises (you're not supposed to wrap a Promise in another Promise constructor).

Let's start with what you could do, then go to what you should do.

You could let the rejection bubble down the Promise chain, re`throw`ing it when it doesn't match your type guard, and at the bottom of the line, after all the `.catch()` clauses exhausted themselves, the Promise returned from your function will reject.

Now

Think about how you would do it in sync code. You'd have something like this:

```
try {
  try {
    actionThatThrows();
  } catch (err) {
    breakEverything();
  }
  continue other steps
} catch(err) {
  generalErrorHandling();
}
```

That kind of code is not OK, and it isn't OK in Promises either. You should move distinct actions into functions which can resolve or reject on their own, use Errors as they were meant, an exception that bubbles up the stack until it meets something that can handle it.

Also, and because you're using TS 2.1.x, for long async flows, an **async function** is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your return is useless there, it's the end of the onRejection callback.
And the return reject() will fulfill the next .then() promise anyway.
However, if you throw the error, it'll be inherited in the following promises down to the .catch(reject);

Basically: in any catch/then, return will resolve the child promise, and throw will reject the child promise.

I rewrote your code for a better flow of the promise chain.

```
public init(): Promise<Array<Proteus.keys.PreKey>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.store.load_identity()
    .catch(
      (error) => {
        if (error instanceof RecordNotFoundError) {
          let identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair = Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair.new();
          return this.store.save_identity(identity);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    )
    .then(
      (identity: Proteus.keys.IdentityKeyPair) => {
        this.identity = identity;
        resolve(this.store.load_prekey(Proteus.keys.PreKey.MAX_PREKEY_ID));
      },
      reject
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my original source code I have a long Promise chain which is like `doSomething > catch > then > then > then > catch > then > then > resolve`. So if I just do `throw error` in my first `catch` block, then my second `catch` block in that chain will be triggered. But I don't want that. I want that the whole chain breaks if there is an error caught in the first `catch` block. That's why I went for `return reject(error);`. But with your solution I cannot follow this pattern. Do you think my problem comes from misusing Promises or am I just missing a type mapping?

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer, The solution you seek is pattern-based, not syntax-based. You need to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32049994/3478010) to the question "How to return from a Promise's catch/then block".