# Promise chain works every time even though the return statement is conditional

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I recently restructured (flattened) this chain. However I am confused as to why this chain **still works in any case** even though the `return` statement in one of the `.then` links is conditional:

```
function addList(name) {
let listObj = {};
listObj.name = name;
return nameExists(name) //returns a promise<boolean>
    .then((result) => {
        console.log("foo");
        return result; //without this return statement the chain would break, 
                       //which makes sense to me because it does not return a 
                       //promise otherwise.
    })
    .then(bool => {
        listObj.unique = !bool;
        if (validListID(name)) { //this is a synchronous regex function
            listObj.unique = false;
        }
        if (!listObj.unique)
            return Counters.getNewShortListId(); // returns Promise
        //Does not return promise when condition not met.
        //However the next chain gets called in any case.
    })
    .then((id) => { //this gets called even when listObj.unique = true,
                    //also this works perfectly, why?
        listObj.__id = id;
        return new List(listObj).save();
    });
}
```

I am really confused as to why this behaves the way it does. I thought the promise chain breaks when no promise is returned?

Comment: [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) -> [*Return value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value): _"... - doesn't return anything, the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with an `undefined` value; ..."_

Comment: JavaScript functions *in general*: if you don't explicitly return a value, they return undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return from a Promise's catch/then block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032588/how-to-return-from-a-promises-catch-then-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't return a Promise from a `.then`, the next `.then` will continue to work just fine (since no error was thrown), but the parameter for its callback will always be `undefined`:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    // don't return anything
  })
  .then((param) => {
    console.log(param);
  });
```

If you're sure that `getNewShortListId`, if, when it resolves, always resolves to a value that is not `undefined`, simply check that the next `.then`'s `id` is not `undefined`.

```
.then((id) => {
    if (id !== undefined) {
        listObj.__id = id;
        return new List(listObj).save();
    }
});
```

Another option is to have the upper `.then` create the Promise instead of having the lower `.then`:

```
if (!listObj.unique)
  return Counters.getNewShortListId()
    .then((id) => {
      listObj.__id = id;
      return new List(listObj).save();
    })
```

If you don't like the look of the nested `.then`s, you could convert the nested `.then` callback to a named function that you declare beforehand (eg `const processId = (id) => ...`).

You can also throw an error (eg `if (listObj.unique) throw new Error()`) to completely break out of the current `.then` chain, and control flow will immediately go to the next `.catch`, skipping intermediate `.then`s - but errors generally shouldn't be used for control flow.