# Break a .finally() chain

Tags: javascript, promise, finally

I have the following chain.

```
  return axios
        .get(actionUrl, {
            params: {
                action: 'action3'
            },
        })
        .finally(() => axios.get(actionUrl, {
            params: {
                action: 'action3'
            },
        }))
        .finally(() => axios.get(actionUrl, {
            params: {
                action: 'action6'
            },
        }))
        .finally(() => axios.get(actionUrl, {
            params: {
                action: 'action1'
            },
        }))
```

I have to sequentially call different endpoints in order even if the previous one fails. However in case an endpoint timeouts I want to break the chain. Is it achievable without using `.then` and `.catch` and repeating the same code in them?

Thanks.

Comment: No. This is precisely what you should use `then` and `catch` for. Why would you want to use `finally`?

Comment: Btw, you already *are* repeating the same code in all lines. Can you post your real code so that we can advise on how to restructure it?

Comment: They are the same calls with different query param which have to be made in order.

Comment: [This might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049994/3478010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable with `then` and `catch`. You should not use `finally` if you don't want the callback to run in case of an error.

> I have to sequentially call different endpoints in order even if the previous one fails. However in case an endpoint timeouts I want to break the chain

So you want to *not* call them when the previous one fails (with a timeout), all you want to do is to ignore non-timeout errors. That's what `catch` should be used for:

```
function callEndpoint(action) {
  return axios.get(actionUrl, { params: { action } }).catch(err => {
    if (isTimeout(err))
      throw err
    else
      ; // ignore the error, return undefined
  })
}
```

Then just chain them:

```
callEndpoint('action3').then(() => callEndpoint('action6')).then(() => callEndpoint('action3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` function is there precisely to make sure that the function inside runs even if there is an exception. You can get the behaviour you want by using just one `finally` like this:

```
axios.get()
  .then(() => doStuffOnSuccess())
  .finally(() => {
    axios.get().then(() => doFinallyStuff1())
       .then(() => doFinallyStuff2())
       .then(() => doFinallyStuff3())
       .catch(e => console.error("Finally had trouble",e));
  });
```

This way if anything within the `finally` function times out or fails it will break the chain. By having the final catch you will avoid it throwing back further up the chain.

This assumes that you are using `finally` correctly and everything in that should always get executed after the previous calls finish even if there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with `async/await`? Generally you shouldn't chain `finally` like this, it's always better to create recurent function for example:

```
const fetchSomething = async () => {
   try { 
     const result = await axios.get();

     if (...when fetching should stop...) {
       return result;
     }

     return fetchSomething();
   } catch(error) {
     return fetchSomething();
   }
}
```

But with reccurent function is extremely important to create some kill switch to prevent executing it forever - for example set some kind of timeout, 1 minute or so and if this limit is exceeded then stop executing.
It will be probably even more easier with `generators` and `yield` but I never used this solution