# Bug: A return won't stop execution when a reject is received and handled

Tags: azure-functions

Steps to reproduce:

Step 1. VSC, F1 to create an auto-gen Azure Function (AF).

Step 2. **index.js**, replace it with below following [MS AF Js developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#use-async-and-await)

```
module.exports = async function (context) 
{
    const good = await db.pgTest({})  // this call will receive a Promise.reject, see below
        .catch
        (
            ce => 
            {
                context.res = {status: 401, body: ce};
                return;   // execution supposed end, but it goes on
            }
        );
    var x = good[0]["column1"];  
    // execution continues to above line even .catch() has a return
    // 'good' will have an array when db.pgTest() succeeds, now is 'undefined'
    // but strangely terminal doesn't print out exception like:
    // Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    

}
```

Step 3. create **db.pgTest()**, a standard Promise. Can be any db calls I'm using `pg-promise`:

```
const pgTest = (param) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        var sql = 'select * from schema.nonexits()';  // simply call a non-exists function to raise a runtime error
        db.any(sql)
        .then
        (
            good => resolve(good),
            bad => 
            {
                reject({status: 401, bad: bad});
            }
        )
        .catch
        (
            ce =>
            {
                reject({status: 402, bad: ce});   // because .then(..., bad=>...) this block is never reached. 
            }
        )
    }
    );
}
```

Environment:

```
Version: 1.63.1 (system setup)
Commit: fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f
Date: 2021-12-14T02:13:54.292Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Azure Functions Extension: v1.6.0
```

Step 4. F5 and hit the URL.

**Update**
My question of `return` is about **index.js**, block `ce => { ... return; }`. I overlooked this block indeed is a **function**.

Comment: It returns from the function it is in. If you want to stop execution, you probably shouldn't catch that exception, or at least rethrow it.

Comment: @tkausl No `.catch` will result `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` aborting execution, client will never receive any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we put the call back request of `PgTest()` Function inside a Promise wrapper `Promise( (resolve, reject) => { //callback function})`. This wrapper allows you to call the `pgTest` function like a promise with `.catch()` methods. When the ***pgTest*** is called, it executes the request to the API and **waits** for either a `resolve()` or a `reject()` statement to execute. In the callback function, you simply pass the retrieved data into the resolve or reject methods. check [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-promise-out-of-a-callback-function-in-javascript-d8ec35d1f981/)

The .catch is a wrapper function of a promise and can be used to catch any exception that happens within the `.then/inside the` block.

[image]

So, the return will be performed, and it will went out of the wrapper function. because the .catch wrapper function can handle every exception in the `.Catch` block

### Updated:

[image]

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032588/how-to-return-from-a-promises-catch-then-block) for more information

Comment: Please read what's [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: My question of `return` is about **index.js**, block `ce => { ... return; }`. I overlooked this block indeed is a **function**.