# Extending Error with ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, error-handling, babeljs

I'm unable to run any of the methods on this `MyError` class.

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super()
    this.name = 'MyError'
    this.message = message
    this.stack = (new Error(message)).stack
    return this
  }
  doSomething () {
    return this.message + " dolphin"
  }
}

let myError = new MyError('Invalid Form.')

console.log(myError.doSomething())
```

For some reason this is giving me an error:

```
console.log(myError.doSomething());
                    ^

TypeError: myError.doSomething is not a function
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/wLmbqg81/)

Comment: There may be some insight here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32750746/340688

Comment: @AndyI think it's a babel specific issue :(

Comment: Where are you executing this? Extending builtins really works only in real ES6 environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out you can't extend Error.

There's a package [`es6-error`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error) with an Error that you can extend.

```
import ExtendableError from 'es6-error';

class MyError extends ExtendableError {
  constructor(message) {
    super()
    this.name = 'MyError'
    this.message = message
    this.stack = (new Error(message)).stack
    return this
  }
  doSomething () {
    return this.message + " dolphin"
  }
}

let myError = new MyError('Invalid Form.')

console.log(myError.doSomething())
```

Comment: Might be worth including the reason why (Babel) in your answer with the link from your comment to make it explicit.