# Custom JavaScript Error formatting in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I would like Chrome Dev Tools to log my custom Error objects (extending `Error`) in the same user-friendly format as a native browser Error.

Currently the following code:

```
 console.log(new CustomError('boom'));
 console.log(new Error('boom'));
```

Produces the following output:

[image]

Instead, I would like my custom error type to display with the ellipsised (`...`) stack trace, with it's convenient clickable file paths when expanded.

My current error implementation is the suggested method of extension from [MDN Custom Error types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types) document, although I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881508/4333) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460753/4333) Stack Overflow answer.

The MDN implementation, with added `captureStackTrace` support, is:

```
function CustomError(message) {
  this.message = message;
  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
  } else {
    this.stack = new Error().stack;
  }
}

 Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomError, Error);
 CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
 CustomError.prototype.name = "CustomError";
 CustomError.prototype.message = "";
 CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError;
```

Is there are way to get Chrome Dev Tools to see my custom error as a standard Error?

Comment: Try poking devtools internals: pop-out the devtools into a separate window, press Ctrl-Shift-I to open devtools for the devtools, set a breakpoint in devtools/bundled/console/console_module.js's _formatMessage, and see what happens when logging various stuff in the first console.

Comment: See also `console.group` and `groupCollapsed`, maybe you can use it as a substitute.

Comment: This might be too much work for your use case, but "custom object formatters" allow you to control how console.log formats objects.