# NodeJS object inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I have an custom error object that is extending the Error object:

```
function GTError(reason, loglevel, meta) {
    winston.log(loglevel, reason, meta);
    GTError.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

util.inherits(GTError, Error);
```

I know that this doesn't work, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript) has workarounds for that. My question isn't how to work around it, my question is **why** doesn't it work? Why does calling `GTError.super_.apply(this, arguments);` (where `GTError.super_` is `Error`) not populate the `message` property of the `this`?

[image]

can you explain, please?
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to show the code for `util.inherits` or if it's from a library, tell which one.

Comment: @JJJ https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Comment: What is `GTError.super_`?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: See robertklep's link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question isn't how to work around it, my question is **why** doesn't it work?

Because the `Error` function always returns a new instance, even if you don't call it with `new`; it doesn't modify the object `this` refers to when you call it. From [the ES5 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.1):

> When `Error` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new `Error` object. Thus the function call `Error(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Error(…)` with the same arguments.

So in your code, `GTError.super_.apply(this, arguments);` (where `GTError.super_` is `Error`) is effectively a no-op, because it creates and throws away an `Error` object rather than making `Error` populate the object passed as `this`. In fact, there's no way (in ES5) to make `Error` populate the object created by `new` in your `new GTError` expression, because of the way `Error` was defined.

The TC-39 committee fixed that in ES2015, but only when you're using the new class stuff (in order to maintain backward compatibility).

---

I know you said you just wanted to know why, but for others: In ES2015 and later, you can correctly subclass `Error` via the new `class` stuff. This syntax is supported in at least Node v4 in strict mode, and universally in Node v6. The following will work in any recent version of Chrome or Firefox:

```js
let winston = {
  log: function(...args) {
    console.log("log", ...args);
  }
};
class GTError extends Error {
    constructor(reason, loglevel, meta) {
        winston.log(loglevel, reason, meta);
        super(reason, loglevel, meta);
    }
}
try {
  throw new GTError("reason", 10, "meta");
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e instanceof Error);
  console.log(e instanceof GTError);
  console.log(e.message);
}
```