# How to rethrow preserving stacktrace in Safari? Safari doesn't show entire stacktrace

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, macos-big-sur

When I rethrow an error, Safari 14.0.3 on macOS Big Sur doesn't print the entire (original) stacktrace. Instead it just points at the rethrow line.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function one() {
  two();
}

function two() {
  three();
}

function three() {
  throw new Error('error from three');
}

try {
  one();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  throw e;
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Running this in my browser Safari 14 prints

[image]

The *actual*  error in the console from the line 21 rethrow,  `throw e;`, only has a one-line stacktrace, pointing at this throw statement on line 21.

The real stacktrace is proven to exist on the error `e` by the log above, `console.log(e)` shows an entire stacktrace from `one()` to `two()` to `three()` to line 14 `throw new Error...`

This seems to be a Safari-only issue, none of Chrome, Firefox, nor Node.js have this problem.

Why doesn't Safari show the entire stacktrace of the rethrown error? How can I force it to do so?

In my in-development website I am doing a couple times:

```
try {
  coinToss();
} catch (e) {
  visuallyPresentErrorInWebpage(e);
  throw e;
}
```

I would *love*  for the browser to automatically show me e's full stacktrace, how can I force it do that?

```
} catch (e) {
  visuallyPresentErrorInWebpage(e);
  console.error(e);
  throw e;
}
```

Is not ideal because now I have duplicated information in the console to slough through.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754270/re-throwing-exception-in-nodejs-and-not-losing-stack-trace may have your answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unfortunately not. This issue does not exist in Node.js, node always prints the full stacktrace even for the rethrow `throw e`. That asker's issue came from creating  a new Error in the first place. I am just rethrowing the original error yet losing the stacktrace.

Comment: Running the first example code in firefox's console I see two stack traces. One called "Error:" another called "Uncaught Error:" - Edit: same in chrome - Where does the image come from?

Comment: I also see two full stack traces in Safari 14.0.3

Comment: @evolutionxbox are you also on Big Sur?

Comment: good point, no. I'm running Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess it's time to downgrade, Apple once again stunning us with progressive updates