# More information about failed tests?

Tags: playwright

How can I bubble up more information about a failed test?
Ideally I want a second parameter on the except function where I can pass a string that would show up on the console. Something like:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
expect( i / j, `failed when dividing ${i} ${j}` )
```

I also tried this:

```
test.describe("Test description", () => {
    test("Test name", async ({ page }) => {
        ...snip...
        await test.step("Testing DIV0 is fail", async () => {
            await expect(4/0).toBe(5);
        });
       ...snip...
    });
});
```

The command line might quickly flash the text `Testing DIV0 is fail` for a 1/1000th of a second. This is not helpful.  Basically Playwright is unusable if I can't find the problem I'm trying to discover.

What I see:

```
  1) myTests.spec.ts:40:2 › Test description 

    Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 5
    Received: Infinity

      44 |              await test.step("Testing DIV0 is fail", async () => {
    > 45 |                      await expect(4/0).toBe(5);
         |                                        ^
      46 |              });


        at myTests.spec.ts:45:22
        at TestTypeImpl._step (...\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\test\testType.js:213:13)
        at Function.step (...\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\test\transform.js:133:12)
        at ...\tests\myTests.spec.ts:44:14
        at WorkerRunner._runTestWithBeforeHooks (...\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\test\workerRunner.js:450:7)

  Slow test: basicPageChecks.spec.ts (24s)

  1 failed
    myTests.spec.ts:40:2 › Test description 
  12 skipped
```

I could just as easily add a comment in the code. Or add logging.

Perhaps this additional data is available in a report?? Am I missing something??

Comment: There is not way to pass an extra message in jest expect (and in playwright expects which extend those). In your example the output clearly says 
`
    Expected: 5
    Received: Infinity
`
so you can see both expected and actual values. What information do you miss in the output?

Comment: In the first code snippet I gave the example of the level of detail I want: `failed when dividing ${i} ${j}`).  I want to be able to pass a string where I can provide what information I would like.  Perhaps the code is looping over a dataset and one example fails. It would be nice to get which piece of data failed. Further more I explain that I do not see the string `Testing DIV0 is fail` which would also satisfy my criteria.

Comment: I was fortunate to speak with someone familiar with playwright it seems that the problem is sort of handled. It's not exactly intuitive. The output from console.log that fall under a `test()` are logged not only at the time of execution but again under a summary that is presented.

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason that console.log is not an answer is that it _always_ logs. The goal is to log extra information only when necessary.

Comment: You can always check your condition manually and throw any message that you like: if (i/j !== 5) throw new Erorr(\`failed when dividing ${i} ${j}\`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from this answer: [Re-throwing exception in NodeJS and not losing stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754270/re-throwing-exception-in-nodejs-and-not-losing-stack-trace)

One good solution (meaning that only errors are logged, it does not require double checking every logical step with an additional if statement, & doesn't triple the number of lines of code with a try/catch wrapping every except) is to do the following:

Add a new class

```
export class RethrownError extends Error {
    constructor(message, error) {
        super(message);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        if (!error) {
            throw new Error("RethrownError requires a message and error");
        } else {
            this.original_error = error;
            this.stack_before_rethrow = this.stack;
            const message_lines =  (this.message.match(/\n/g)||[]).length + 1;
            this.stack = this.stack.split("\n").slice(0, message_lines+1).join("\n") + "\n" + error.stack;
        }
    }
    static expectWithMessage(message, cb) {
        try {
            cb()
        } catch(ex) {
            throw new RethrownError(message, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

change the except from

```
await expect(4/0).toBe(5);
```

to

```
await RethrownError.expectWithMessage("DIV by zero", () => {expect(4/0).toBe(5); });
```

Problem with this solution is that the expect line is pretty ugly (line length).

Hopefully someday MS would update `expect()` to accept a second error message parameter.