# What are the differences between throwing error and throwing function with error prototype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I saw a very special (and weird) error handling code, which goes like this:

```
function SomeError(name, message) {
    this.name = name;
    this.message = message;
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
SomeError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

On promise catch:

```
promise.catch(e => {
    throw new SomeError('someName', e.message);
});
```

My question:
Is there any reasonable cause to make it this way?
I thought of handling this like:

```
promise.catch(e => {
    e.name = 'my error name';
    throw new Error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it allows you to fine grain the catching:

```
 // Somewhere up the promise chain:
 .catch(error => {
    if(error instanceof SomeError) {
      // Handle this specific case
    } else { /* handle other cases */}
  });
```

The code that defines `SomeError` could be rewritten as the following class which makes clear what it is doing:

```
 class SomeError extends Error {}
```

It basically just creates a subclass that does nothing.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1382107/1048572) for various pre-ES6 ways to extend `Error`