# Custom Error Class Extending Error With Getters

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter, custom-errors

I want to create my own error class that extends the base JS Error class and has mutliple getters defined.

example:

```js
class CustomError extends Error {
  public get code(): string {
    return "my-code";
  }
}

const myError = new CustomError("uuu");

console.log("message", myError.message); // the message "uuu"
console.log("code", myError.code); // undefined
```

The problem is that if I want to get the getter value I get undefined in return and not the desired value.

Does anybody know why this is how it is or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

edit: my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom","es6", "es2016"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "include": [ "src/**/*.ts" ]
}
```

see repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/DentalVoluminousPerformance

Comment: It seems to be working in a clean environment: https://repl.it/repls/StridentShyTelevisions

Comment: Yes if you set the Typescript compile target to `es6` but it fails with `es5` ...

Comment: I think this may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error