# Calling Vuex action from within another vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex4, vue-devtools

I recently migrated to the `Vuex` store, and I am making a decent amount of progress. But the current challenge I face is calling an action from within another action in Vuex. I am still in the process of learning Vue.js

`Current versions`

1. `Vue 3`
2. `Vuex 4`
3. If needed I use `Electron Vue.js dev tools`

`/src/store/index.js` - Current code

```js
/* eslint-disable no-redeclare */

import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    ...
  },
  mutations: {
    setQuery(state, query) {
      // refers this.state.query
      state.query = query
    },

    setOnlinePresenceInitialPageLoad(state, presence) {
      // refers this.state.online & this.state.initialPageLoad
      state.online = presence
      state.initialPageLoad = false
    },

    setRequestErrorAndStatus(state, { _status, code }) {
      // refers this.state.request.error & this.state.request._status
      state.request.error = _status
      state.request._status = code
    },

    setResults(state, processed) {
      state.request.results = processed
    }
  },
  actions: {
    callApi({ commit, state, dispatch }) {
      axios.get(state.axios.targetURL, {
        baseURL: state.axios.config.baseURL,
        params: {
          days: state.axios.config.params.days,
          q: state.query,
          key: state.axios.config.params.key,
        },
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.status)
        commit('setOnlinePresenceInitialPageLoad', true);
        dispatch('formatResults', response.data);
      }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.status)
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log(error.request.status)
        } else {
          console.log("Couldn't find the problem")
        }
      })
    },
    formatResults(context, payload) {
      const processedData = {
          ...
      }
      console.log(processedData);
      context.commit('setResults', processData);
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

As you can see the `callApi()` calls the `formatResults()` in the fulfilled section of the Promise.

`Current state (Web browser)`

[image: Current state in the web browser console]

In the code, I tried logging out the variable `processedData`. I thought it would be printed on the console.

`Current state (Vue Devtools)`

[image: Current state in Vue.js devtools]

I would also like to know why `formatResults()` never ends.

Can this problem be solved with async functions, if yes then I would like to know the procedures to take?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your screenshots don't tell us much. Can you put a `console.log` at the start and end of formatResults` and confirm that the second one never fires? And equivalently before and after it is dispatched in `callAPI`?

Comment: the problem is that is fires but for some reason never ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hard to tell from the information provided, but I'm going to venture a guess here...

seeing that `console.log(response.status)` and then `console.log("Couldn't find the problem")` were triggered, as well as `formatResults` (from the vuex screenshot) I suspect that `formatResults` is throwing an error.

```js
formatResults(context, payload) {
  const processedData = {
      // the error could be somewhere here
  }
  console.log(processedData);
  context.commit('setResults', processData);
}
```

when the error occurs, the `catch` will handle it

```js
if (error.response) {
  console.log(error.response.status)
} else if (error.request) {
  console.log(error.request.status)
} else {
  // handled here with log ...
  console.log("Couldn't find the problem")
}
```

try using `console.error(error)` to see what the cause of the error is

```js
if (error.response) {
  console.log(error.response.status)
} else if (error.request) {
  console.log(error.request.status)
} else {
  console.error(error)
}
```

and then you might have enough information to debug the source of the problem

Comment: thanks I found the issue

Comment:  gotta watch that error handling. I would recommend using custom error types and `instance of` to validate that you're handling the right error. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript for more info) and then for `else` use `throw error` so that unhandled errors bubble up