# Can someone explain this JavaScript code to me?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

```
// Create an object type UserException  
function UserException (message){  
  this.message=message;  
  this.name="UserException";  
}  

// Make the exception convert to a pretty string when used as  
// a string (e.g. by the error console)  
UserException.prototype.toString = function (){  
  return this.name + ': "' + this.message + '"';  
}  

// Create an instance of the object type and throw it  
throw new UserException("Value too high");
```

How will this be used?

Comment: Are you familiar with throwing exceptions?  I'm trying to determine what level to explain this at.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464359/custom-exceptions-in-javascript

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

Comment: Wait, what does the UserException.prototype do here?

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can create objects in javascript, in this case, a `UserException` object with a `toString` function. It might be used like so:

```
try {
    throw new UserException("something went wrong");
} catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```