# Can I throw an exception in Javascript, that stops Javascript execution?

Tags: javascript

I try to simulate a problem where a script that is loaded from an external url stops execution of any more scripts on my site.

I tried to simulate such a problem by calling a function that does not exits. I can see the error in firebug but different scripts on the page are still executed.

Are there different kinds of errors in Javascripts? If yes: what kind of error stops script execution? I only need this answer for Firefox.

**EDIT**

This question is easy to misunderstood but Rob W got it: I need to throw an exception and that exception needs to stop further script execution.

Comment: `throw new Error("Something bad happened.")` or http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_throw.asp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464359/custom-exceptions-in-javascript

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Answer to the title: **No**
>   Answer to "Are there different kinds of errors in JavaScript**: Yes, see MDN: [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)
>   Syntax errors will prevent a whole script block from being executed,
>   other errors (TypeErrors, Reference errors) will only stop the execution after the occurrence of the error.

Different `<script>` blocks are executed separately. You cannot prevent the second block from execution by throwing an error in the first block (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WJCEN/).

```
<script>Example: Syntax error in this script.</script>
<script>console.log('Still executed.')</script>
```

Also, if an error is caught using `try-catch` (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WJCEN/1/), then the error will not even stop the execution a whole block.

```
try {throw 'Code';}catch(e){}
console.log('Still executed');
```

---

There is no general one-fit-all method to stop all code from running. For individual scripts, you can use some tricks to prevent the code from running further.

### Example 1 ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaA4t/)): Temporary overwrite a method

```
1: <script>window._alert = alert;alert=null;</script>
2: <script>alert('Some code!');confirm('Not executing');</script>
3: <script>alert=_alert;delete window._alert;alert('Done!');</script>
```

This method is based on the fact that script 2 expects `alert` to be a function. We have rewritten `alert` to a non-function property (script 1). Script 2 throws a `TypeError`, and the second block is skipped.
We restore the original values in script 3.

### Example 2 ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaA4t/1/)): Define a constant method, which cannot be overwritten.

```
4. <script>Object.defineProperty(window, 'test',{value:null});</script>
5. <script>var test=function(){alert('Test');};test();alert('What?');</script>
```

This methods relies on the [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method, to effectively define a constant value. In strict mode, the `var test` declaration would throw a TypeError: "test is read-only".
When strict mode is not enables, a TypeError will be thrown at `test()`: "test is not a function" (because we defined `test` to be constant, in script 4).

Note: The last method is not working correctly with function declarations (see [bug #115452](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115452), Chrome 17)

Comment: I guess that if I reference an external script file that this counts a  different  script block. Am I right?

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner Yes. See my updated answer. There is no single solution for all cases, the right approach differs per case.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the error object which  support the following two properties:

```
name: The name of the error.
message: A description of the error.
```

for example to stop  execution you can use : `throw new Error("myError");`

> Are there different kinds of errors in Javascripts?

Besides the generic Error constructor, there are six other core errors in JavaScript:

see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) details on these errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`try catch finally block`

It will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Stop the execution with

```
throw new Error('stopIt');
```

This will also do the trick:

```
throw 'Stop It!';
```

Comment: But won't stop like what OP was looking for, errors will only stop the single script block from executing, take a look at the accepted answer