# AJAX silently failing when loading script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just notice a weird behavior when dynamically loading scripts with AJAX.
I intentionally have a  misspelled code that throws an error when it is parsed. Even though the Chrome's console indeed shows the error, the AJAX fail handler is never called.

This is the function that I use to load files:

```
var load_source = function (path) {
    /* Variable used to determine whether the request was successful */
    var success = false,
        failed;

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: path,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'script',
            method: 'GET'
        }
    ).
        done(function () {
            success = true;
        }).
        fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            failed = error.stack ? error.stack : error;
        });

    if (failed)
    {
        throw new Error('Unable to load JS file {0}: {1}'.format(path, failed));
    }
}
```

The only variable provided to the load_source function is **"path"**, which value is a string with the location and name of such a file: "js/myFile.js".

The misspelled part (the part with a typo) of the script to load is this:

```
var f = function (arg) {
    var param1 = 3,
        param2, /* NOTICE the typo: there is a comma instead of a semicolon */

    if (param1 > arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // And more code is coming next...
```

If I look at the Chrome's console, it shows the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if**

So far the only way I can catch the error is with the window's onerror event.

So, if that is the only way to catch the error, could you tell me how to stop the "coding" flow, I mean, whenever I call *load_source* that throws an error (which is handled by the window's **onerror** function) I want the  script to do nothing else:

```
load_source('js/myFile.js'); // This script will throw the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if" error.
// So I don't want the following code to be executed.
sum(4, 3);
mul(5, 5);
// ...
```

Can you guys tell me how make the fail event to be triggered?

I also tried with " $(document).ajaxError" but with the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I throw an exception in Javascript, that stops Javascript execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431434/can-i-throw-an-exception-in-javascript-that-stops-javascript-execution)

Comment: `async: false` and `dataType: 'script'` don't mix. Because this request is made using a <script> tag, there is no good way of catching an error from it or having said error prevent future code from running other than what you've already observed.

Comment: @KevinB That is only true for cross-domain scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's async stuff :) There is no way that the resource fetching (`load_source(url)`) is going to be finished before your `sum()` and `mul()` functions are executed.

The things you want to make dependable on the successful loading of your remote resource, should be placed in a callback, which is executed *after* success of the resource fetching.

**UPDATE**

- Regarding the "aysnc: false" in your example, and mentioned in the
  comments: this applies only to the `$.ajax()` function scope, not to
  the parent function.
- Also: `is_empty` is not part of the standard
  library, I assume you have defined that function elsewhere?

Comment: Not necessarily. He is using `async: false`.

Comment: I'm using the async property as false, will be the same result?

Comment: But the thing that really maters to me is about the error/exception thrown that is not caught by the fail event

Comment: @imtheman async inside of a function doesn't affect the function itself... Checkout my JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6rLsaor3/1/ and open up your console.

Comment: @JethroVanThuyne I was not expecting that... I understand what you mean now. Thank you for that.

Comment: @JethroVanThuyne Actually, I was right. The docs state `Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.` And also, `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Still, the `async` property in the ajax call applies to the ajax-function scope, not to the calling function. See the forked JSFiddle here, requesting a non-crossdomain script: https://jsfiddle.net/9tr5uy8h/ Same behaviour.

Comment: @JethroVanThuyne That's just not how synchronicity works. https://jsfiddle.net/hdem4ppj/

Comment: Aha. I wasn't aware of the different behaviour between this syntax and the chained methods syntax in the example of OP. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

The fail event is being triggered, it's just not stopping the rest of the JS from running. You'd be better off doing some thing like this:

```
if(load_source('js/myFile.js'))
{
   sum(4, 3);
   mul(5, 5);
}
```

Then removing your `throw` in your `load_source()` function and using `return success;`, like so:

```
var load_source = function (path) {
    /* Variable used to determine whether the request was successful */
    var success = false;

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: path,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'script',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(){
               success = true;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               console.log(error.stack ? error.stack : error);
            }
        }
    );

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Hi @imtheman,
I edited the code to this:

    if (failed)
    {
        throw new Error('Unable to load JS file {0}: {1}'.format(path, failed));
    }

and again, even though the console shows the error, the "fail" handler is never triggered ("failed" variable is assigned a value in the "fail" handler ).

Also, don't get what you mean with *Then removing your `throw` in your `load_source()` function and using 11return submit;`*

Comment: I also change the fail ($.Deferred) for "error" AJAX object propertie but the error is never caught.

Comment: Take a look at the changes I made.

Comment: The documentation specficially notes that the fail callback may not be called when the data type is set to script or jsonp.

Comment: `fail`, `error: fn`, same thing. it doesn't get called due to the error just not being catchable.

Comment: @KevinB From the docs: `This handler is not called for cross-domain scripts`. this is only true for cross-domain scripts.

Comment: imtheman, I tried your code but still the "fail" handler was not triggered.
@KevinB, can you point me out to such documentation? Looking at here: "https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/" it is mentioned that one can handle errors with the "fail" handler.