# Throwing user defined error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to throw an exception in javascript, I am trying to give exception a number along with the message, but i am only getting the message alone and not the number why? what am i doing wrong?
my code is:

```
function ain()
{
    var e = new Error("hello guys" ,12345);
    throw e;
}

(function() {
    try {
       ain();
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e.number+"     "+e.message);
    }
}());
```

The output is :

```
undefined     hello guys
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1137209/921204

Comment: There is no `number` member of Error -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: @Noyo There is a number member for error in Internet Explorer 10. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dww52sbt(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @JurgenStillaert It is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Error` constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) does not take a "number" property. It only takes a string message (the other two parameters are non-standard so I will not mention them).

If you really need to use a fully customized error object, you can just throw an object literal instead of an error:

```
try {
    throw { message: 'hello world', number: 12345};
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.number + ': ' + e.message);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHc7v/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a number that isn't a line number as a second parameter, you might want to consider creating a new error type, that inherits from the main `Error` prototype:

```
function MyError(msg, num)
{
    this.name = 'MyError';
    this.message = msg;
    this.number = num || 0;
}
MyError.prototype = new Error;
MyError.prototype.constructor = MyError;
//and if you want:
MyError.prototype.alertMsg = function()
{
    alert(this.name + ': ' + this.message + ' -- ' + this.number);
};
```

This augmented error object can be used as you want:

```
function iThrow()
{
    throw new MyError('I throw errors with numbers', 123);
}
try
{
    iThrow();
}
catch(e)
{
    e.alertMsg();//alerts "MyError: I throw errors with numbers -- 123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find more information, and it is also browser specific:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljfhismo.php

Answer (score -1):

If you look the description for this method You will see that second parameter is file name not number and third option is line number of error not error code.

```
new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])
```

Comment: You can use `Exception` if you want to, but I'd prefer using constructors/prototypes that actually exist. In JS there is no such thing as an `Exception` prototype...