# Exception Message in Ajax error callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have triggering an Ajax call and in the error callback I am trying to access the exception message(Not the Response Text). I am throwing an exception like this:

```
throw new Exception("Please enter a response")
```

Now I want to get the above message and display it in alert box.

I searched stackoverflow and found this:

```
 error: function(e,status){
                var err = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
```

but the above doesn't work.

I am getting the response text but not able to access that particular message.

The error that I am getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 0):

When your server throws an Internal Server Error, from Javascript side it's still a succes. how about adding the Status code response instead of throwing exception from the backend

```
 return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Custom Error Message 2");
```

Comment: I am able to catch the error in the error callback. Its not a success but I want to extract the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724419/2968762) and try to get error message as `alert(err.message);` **(lowercase)** not `alert(err.Message);`